# fastlane ** ARCHIVE FAILED **

Tags: xcode, xcodebuild, fastlane

***no rule to process file '/Users/user/Desktop/gugu-ios/TPComics/Pods/TPShareSDK/TPShareSDK/Classes/Framework/TencentOpenAPI.framework/TencentOpenAPI' of type 'archive.ar' for architecture 'armv7' (in target 'TPShareSDK' from project 'Pods')***

***no rule to process file '/Users/user/Desktop/gugu-ios/TPComics/Pods/TPShareSDK/TPShareSDK/Classes/Framework/TencentOpenAPI.framework/TencentOpenAPI' of type 'archive.ar' for architecture 'arm64' (in target 'TPShareSDK' from project 'Pods')***

** ARCHIVE FAILED **

**The following build commands failed:
    Ld /Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TouchManga-ccdmpbvljruieagdgaaqmiqwjkct/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/TouchManga/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/TouchManga.build/Release-iphoneos/TouchManga.build/Objects-normal/armv7/Binary/TouchManga normal armv7**

**(1 failure)**

**Exit status: 65**

***my part of Fastfile is :***

```
    scheme_name = "TouchManga"
    export_method = "app-store" 
    configuration = "Release"
    plist = "./TPComics/Info.plist"

    # 设置build
    curTime = Time.new.strftime("%Y%m%d")
    build_number = get_info_plist_value(path: "#{plist}", key: 'CFBundleVersion')
    version_number = get_version_number(target: "#{scheme_name}")
    #TODO   

    # 提示
    puts "building #{scheme_name} version #{version_number} build #{build_number} ..."


    # gym用来编译ipa
    gym(
      scheme: "#{scheme_name}",
      output_directory: './fastlane/build',
      output_name: "#{scheme_name}_#{build_number}",
      export_method: "#{export_method}",
      configuration: "#{configuration}",
      clean:true,
    )
```

[TPShareSDK build-settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b8K1J.png)

[target build-settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SusXe.png)

how can i solve this problem?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Xcode 12, building for iOS Simulator, but linking in an object file built for iOS, for architecture 'arm64'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63607158/xcode-12-building-for-ios-simulator-but-linking-in-an-object-file-built-for-io)