# Xcode building for iOS Simulator, but linking in an object file built for iOS, for architecture 'arm64'

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods, arm64, xcode12

I am trying to get a large (and working on Xcode 11!) project building in Xcode 12 (beta 5) to prepare for iOS 14. The codebase was previously in Objective-C, but now it contains both Objective-C and Swift, and uses pods that are Objective-C and/or Swift as well.

I have pulled the new beta of [CocoaPods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CocoaPods) with Xcode 12 support (currently 1.10.0.beta 2).

Pod install is successful.  When I do a build, I get the following error on a pod framework:

> building for iOS Simulator, but linking in object file built for iOS, for architecture arm64

and possibly also the error:

> Unable to load standard library for target 'arm64-apple-ios11.0'

When I go run `lipo -info` on the framework, it has: armv7s armv7 i386 x86_64 arm64.

Previously, the project had *Valid Architectures* set to: armv7, armv7s and arm64.

In Xcode 12, that setting goes away, as per Apple's documentation.  Architectures is set to $(ARCHS_STANDARD).  I have nothing set in excluded architectures.

What may be going on here?  I have not been able to reproduce this with a simpler project yet.

Comment: This is worked for me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24924809/the-file-myapp-app-couldnt-be-opened-because-you-dont-have-permission-to-vi/64016147#64016147

Comment: Check out the article: https://milanpanchal24.medium.com/xcode-12-building-for-ios-simulator-but-linking-in-object-file-built-for-ios-file-for-8c0cc28ec832?sk=adfc406c1f4fae81155cd4a49ec7edb4

Comment: Conversely, if you want to build with arm64 bc now you have Apple M1, in Applications folder, r-click on Xcode icon, select `Get Info`, and check the `open using rosetta` option. Relaunch Xcode or CLI

Comment: TLDR; XCode 13 + Apple M1: (1) Open Xcode using Rosetta (Applications -> Right-Click Xcode -> Get Info -> Check Open with Rosetta). (2) Add `arm64` to excluded architectures (Build Settings) (3) Clean Build Folder (4) Run app

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70939338/10678427 This worked for me. It may work for you as well.

Comment: See [this comprehensive answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63607158/xcode-building-for-ios-simulator-but-linking-in-an-object-file-built-for-ios-f/75454378#75454378) for a detailed explanation of platform vs architecture, fat binary vs xcframework, ways of inspecting binaries, differences of the flags, Apple's recommendation and more.

Comment: Note that if you are using XCode 14.3 or higher that the `Open using Rosetta` has been removed. If you run into build or deployment issues regarding running on a Simulator when building on an M1 or M2 Apple Silicon using these versions of XCode then https://stackoverflow.com/a/77538450/333325 may be of use. Targeting Rosetta Simulator may be required if your build contains libraries that do not yet provide XCFrameworks that support running on both x86_64 and arm64 architectures

Answer (score 1314, accepted):

Basically, you have to exclude `arm64` for the simulator architecture, both from your project and the Pod project.

- To do that, navigate to **Build Settings** of your project and add *Any iOS Simulator SDK* with value `arm64` inside *Excluded Architecture*.

  [image]

**OR**

- If you are using custom `XCConfig` files, you can simply add this line for excluding simulator architecture.

  ```
  EXCLUDED_ARCHS[sdk=iphonesimulator*] = arm64
  ```

  **Then**

  You have to do the same for the **Pod project** until all the Cocoa pod vendors are done adding following in their **Podspec**.

  ```rb
  s.pod_target_xcconfig = { 'EXCLUDED_ARCHS[sdk=iphonesimulator*]' => 'arm64' }
  s.user_target_xcconfig = { 'EXCLUDED_ARCHS[sdk=iphonesimulator*]' => 'arm64' }
  ```

  You can manually add the *Excluded Architecture* in your Pod project's **Build Settings**, but it will be overwritten when you
  use `pod install`.

  In place of this, you can add this snippet in your `Podfile`. It will write the necessary **Build Settings** every time you run `pod install`.

  ```
  post_install do |installer|
    installer.pods_project.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings["EXCLUDED_ARCHS[sdk=iphonesimulator*]"] = "arm64"
    end
  end
  ```

Comment: @DominatorVbN So all dependancies for a Podspec has to exclude right?

Comment: The extra detail about CocoaPods here is nice. Note that without `[sdk=iphonesimulator*]` after `EXCLUDED_ARCHS`, XCode will fail to find your pods when building for an actual device since none of the pods will be built for arm64.

Comment: @ChrisVanBuskirk Yes every Dependencies and there Sub Dependencies need to exclude, as of now many cocoapod vender are already exculid via there Podspec, but until all have done migrating we can attach this little snippet in out pod file to exclude it while installing the pod.

Comment: It's working in the device & getting error in Simulator.

Comment: Worked for me! Note that there is already a `post_install do |installer|` section in most Podfiles due to flipper. Paste the inner section ```installer.pods_project.build_configurations.each do |config|
    config.build_settings["EXCLUDED_ARCHS[sdk=iphonesimulator*]"] = "arm64"
  end``` behind the `flipper_post_install(installer)` line.

Comment: I am getting `building for iOS Simulator, but linking in object file built for macOS, for architecture x86_64`. How to fix it?

Comment: Note: You have to repeat step one for every scheme you have

Comment: The solution has a flaw that causes trouble since pod spec authors have found and applied this solution. The problematic part is the use of `user_target_xcconfig`. Since multiple pod specs define differing values for `EXCLUDED_ARCHS` they are in conflict and CocoaPods emits warnings like this `[!] Can't merge user_target_xcconfig for pod targets: [... list of pods ...]. Singular build setting EXCLUDED_ARCHS[sdk=<...>] has different values.` The podspec syntax reference says this attribute is "not recommended" https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podspec.html#user_target_xcconfig

Comment: I suggest checking out https://stackoverflow.com/a/64150387/2399348

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Could you explain why this is required?

Comment: @WojciechKulik https://stackoverflow.com/a/64139830/11857852 this answer explains nicely what has been changed in Xcode, our simulator now run on x86 but the framework tries to build for arm64 too.

Comment: if my podspec includes dependencies (for example ss.dependency 'Mantle', '2.1.4') how to exclude arm64 for this dependency too? seems that if I just add s.pod_target_xcconfig = { 'EXCLUDED_ARCHS[sdk=iphonesimulator*]' => 'arm64' }
s.user_target_xcconfig = { 'EXCLUDED_ARCHS[sdk=iphonesimulator*]' => 'arm64' } it doesn't affect dependencies

Comment: This worked for me. I had multiple targets. So Excluded Architectures added to the "Project", not to the "Targets"

Comment: @jiaweiwang what about the `ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH` solution that I have mentioned here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64139830/2650641?

Comment: This ends up working sometimes, but is actually wrong and broken. EXCLUDED_ARCHS for arm64 on the simulator means that people with Apple Silicon macs won't be able to use your framework. The fix that actually worked for me was to clear out VALID_ARCHS as per https://stackoverflow.com/a/63714000/234

Comment: In the new 12.3 Xcode, if you exclude the architecture, it no longer finds the framework.  I submitted this as a bug and opened a ticket with Apple.  Will update when I have info.

Comment: man, you saved my day. Anyone who comes here from react native and have this https://github.com/wix/Detox/issues/2554 issue, this solution works perfectly.

Comment: Besides the project I had to do this inside the project folder -> CordovaLib.xcodeproj file to make it work.

Comment: Unfortunately, recommending that pods add those lines to their podspec is actually going to cause a lot of problems. Having a single pod with that `user_target_xcconfig` line in its podspec will cause the app to not build properly for simulators on an Apple Silicon Mac. And it's really hard to track down, because the error will manifest when it tries to import another pod that has been (correctly) built for arm64, making it look like a problem with a different pod.

Comment: This is not an answer - it is a temporary workaround. You need to contact the vendors of your dependencies and ask them to vend proper XCFrameworks that contain the arm64 Simulator slice. Excluding the arm64 slice can significantly impact Simulator performance on M1 devices.

Comment: This is not working at my end. I have added frameworks in the project. It build successfully but when I use it in example project. It says image not found for frameworks.

Comment: I'm able to build & run on Simulator on Apple Sillicon, but unit tests for internal frameworks do not run with this

Comment: I am not using pod in my objective-c project. Facing the error. But the above solution not worked in 12.5.1.

Comment: Xcode - 13 ??? just try adding excluded-architecture - both debug and release to : arm64, & build excluded architecture to: yes

Comment: I wonder since we need arm64 for real devices, why do we exclude arm64 in simulators on M1? Are arm64 in devices and simulators different?

Comment: This helped me fix the issues when moving my SwiftUI project from an intel machine to the  M1 Pro. Had to ensure that "All" & "Combined" are selected in options for the Architectures configs to show

Comment: for tvOS you'd need to use the following:
config.build_settings['EXCLUDED_ARCHS[sdk=appletvsimulator*]'] = 'arm64'

But in my situation the library was one I had in my project that wasn’t integrated with Cocoapods because it’s private from a 3rd party vendor so I had to manually update to a newer library.

Comment: Encountered an issue where 'PrivatePod' module was not found for 'arm64' when compiling for iOS simulator on an Intel machine using Xcode 14. Solved it by excluding 'arm64' for simulator builds in the .podspec:
``` spec.pod_target_xcconfig = { 'EXCLUDED_ARCHS[sdk=iphonesimulator*]' => 'arm64' } ```
This tells CocoaPods to exclude 'arm64' when building for the simulator. Useful for Intel Macs. Hope this helps others!

Comment: Thank you! Adding iOS Simulator SDK with value arm64 inside Excluded Architecture solved my problem.

Answer (score 286):

TL;DR;

Set "Build Active Architecture Only (`ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH`)" to **Yes** for your libraries/apps, even for **release** mode.

---

While trying to identify the root cause of the issue I realized some fun facts about Xcode 12.

1. Xcode 12 is actually the stepping stone for [Apple silicon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_silicon) which unfortunately is not yet available (*when the answer was written*). But with that platform we are going to get an arm64-based macOS where simulators will also run on the arm64 architecture unlike the present Intel-based *x86_64* architecture.
2. Xcode usually depends on the "Run Destination" to build its libraries/applications. So when a simulator is chosen as the "Run Destination", it builds the app for available simulator architectures and when a device is chosen as the "Run Destination" it builds for the architecture that the device supports (`arm*`).
3. `xcodebuild`, in the Xcode 12+ build system considers `arm64` as a valid architecture for simulator to support Apple silicon. So when a simulator is chosen as the run destination, it can potentially try to compile/link your libs/apps against `arm64` based simulators, as well. So it sends `clang(++)` some -target flag like `arm64-apple-ios13.0-simulator` in <architecture>-<os>-<sdk>-<destination> format and clang tries to build/link against an arm64-based simulator that eventually fails on an Intel based Mac.
4. But `xcodebuild` tries this only for **Release** builds. Why? Because, "Build Active Architecture Only (`ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH`)" build settings is usually set to "No" for the "Release" configuration only. And that means `xcodebuild` will try to build all architectural variants of your libs/apps for the selected run destination for release builds. And for the Simulator run destination, it will includes both `x86_64` and `arm64` now on, **since `arm64` in Xcode 12+ is also a supported architecture for simulators** to support Apple silicon.

Simply putting, Xcode will fail to build your application anytime it tries the command line, `xcodebuild`, (which defaults to release build, see the general tab of your project setting) or otherwise and **tries to build all architectural variants supported by the run destination**. So a simple workaround to this issue is to set "Build Active Architecture Only (`ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH`)" to **Yes** in your libraries/apps, even for release mode.

[image]

[image]

If the libraries are included as Pods and you have access to `.podspec` you can simply set:

> spec.pod_target_xcconfig = { 'ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH' => 'YES' }

> spec.user_target_xcconfig = { 'ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH' => 'YES' } # not
> recommended

I personally don't like the second line since [pods shouldn't pollute the target project](https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podspec.html#user_target_xcconfig) and it could be overridden in the target settings, itself. So it should be the responsibility of the consumer project to override the setting by some means. However, **this could be necessary for successful linting of podspecs.**

However, if you don't have access to the `.podspec`, you can always update the settings during installation of the pods:

```
post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings["ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH"] = "YES"
    end
  end
end
```

One thing I was concerned about that what will be the impact of this when we actually archive the libraries and applications. During archiving applications usually take the "Release" configuration and since this will be creating a release build considering only the active architecture of the current run destination, with this approach, we may lose the slices for armv7, armv7s, etc. from the target build. However, I noticed the documentation says (highlighted in the attached picture) that this setting will be ignored when we choose "Generic iOS Device/Any Device" as the run destination, since it doesn't define any specific architecture. So I guess we should be good if we archive our app choosing that as a run destination.

Comment: I managed to get it all working in the end with 'EXCLUDED_ARCHS[sdk=iphonesimulator*]' => 'arm64' but only in pod_target_xcconfig, and only on the problem pod (which included a prebuilt library) and the single pod which depended on the problem pod. Everything else was left clean. I decided I preferred that to the active arch solution.

Comment: Would not building only the active architecture cause issues with release builds during App Store/TestFlight submission?

Comment: @BalázsVincze No it won't.

1. Building for only active architecture when a specific run destination is chosen (simulator/iPhone/iPad) will build for only active architecture that the device supports.

2. For "Any iOS device" run destination (which is used for archiving during submission) -- "This setting will be ignored when building with a run destination which does not define a specific architecture, such as a 'Generic Device' run destination.", as per documentation. Please see the last paragraph of my answer.

I personally have submitted my apps several times with this setting on.

Comment: On Apple Silicon, doing this lead to another error. This may be due to some specific pods. I opened a specific question for theses cases. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65364886/react-native-on-apple-silicon-m1-the-linked-library-libpods-projectname-a-is

Comment: I am getting 
Showing All Errors Only
Build input file cannot be found: '/Users/name/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/app-ecboaqtowbxrpjbrefynpxlxmyxr/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/app hello.app/App Hello'

Comment: @sejn you have mentioned file missing in your working tree. Please verify if it is there searching from Project Navigator. But this is completely out of the scope of this answer. You can create a separate question if you feel.

Comment: @AyanSengupta If I remove the product name it works fine. But I can't able to install  the file and got /Users/name/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Project-hbaothufasjichbdcaldiltth/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/.app is not a valid path to an executable file.Please rebuild the project to ensure that all required executables are created. Check your project settings to ensure that a valid executable will be built.

Comment: This is good workaround when building for simulator on Intel based Mac on Xcode > 12, to hint Xcode that we are building for simulator having x86_64 architecture. Unfortunately it does not work for M1 & simulator (where you can as workaround run Xcode on Rosetta and include whats proposed by Ayan Sengupta). Proper answer is really done by Tony Arnold - it's all about having proper ARM slice (and XCFramework conversion) for simulator in your Pod, and should be done by vendor of Pod.

Comment: SHOULD BE: spec.pod_target_xcconfig = { 'EXCLUDED_ARCHS[sdk=iphonesimulator*]' => 'arm64' }
spec.user_target_xcconfig = { 'EXCLUDED_ARCHS[sdk=iphonesimulator*]' => 'arm64' }

Answer (score 164):

I found a solution! *[SwiftUI Previews not working with Firebase](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/657913)*

If you set excluded architectures for the simulator to arm64 it will compile.

[image: Excluding architectures for the simulator]

Comment: I was testing on **Release** mode so I had to add it to Release too

Comment: This got me past the initial build failure, but past that there were 30+ new bright red errors all over the place in multiple packages.

Comment: This worked for me, but only when I build for arm64; simulators don't work. Small rant: xCode is ridiculous, 12.5 gigs, tons of pods. Building for Android is a walk in the park compared to this experience.

Comment: This won't work on M1 mac

Comment: I only needed this for M1 Mac and it works (without Rosetta; with Rosetta I didn't have this problem at all)

The answer, for me, is in the project that I'm trying to compile
1. Architectures are standard
2. Build active is NO
3. Excluded is Debug -> Any iOS Sim SDK -> arm64 but all other slots are blank

Hopefully this helps somebody else, too.

Comment: I add these code lines in the pod file additionally.
///////////////
`installer.pods_project.build_configurations.each do |config|       
    config.build_settings["EXCLUDED_ARCHS[sdk=iphonesimulator*]"] = "arm64"
end`
///////////////

Answer (score 124):

The proposed answers are outdated/incorrect.

You should initially try to **update both [CocoaPods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CocoaPods) and the dependencies for your library/app**, and then, if that doesn't work, contact the vendors of any dependencies you are using to see if they have an update in progress to add support for arm64 Simulator slices on [M1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_M1) Macs.

There are a lot of answers on here marked as correct suggesting that you should exclude arm64 from the list of supported architectures. This is at best a very temporary workaround, and at worst it will spread this issue to other consumers of your libraries. If you exclude the arm64 Simulator slice, there will be performance impacts on apps that you're developing in the Simulator (which in turn can lead to reduced battery time for your shiny new M1 kit while you're developing your amazing ideas).

Comment: That's true, as mangling with excluding or including architectures works solely on i386-based machines.

Answer (score 78):

The Valid Architectures build setting has been removed in Xcode 12.  If you had values in this build setting, they're causing a problem and need to be removed.

I was able to "clear out" the VALID_ARCHS build setting by adding it back in as a user-defined build setting (with no values), running the project (which failed), and then deleting the VALID_ARCHS build setting.  After that, I was able to run on the simulator.

My *Architectures* build setting is *Standard Architectures*.

You can add a user-defined setting from the plus button in *Build Settings*:

[image: User-defined setting]

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Make sure the app project is selected not the Target. Otherwise, you won't be able to delete the VALID_ARCHS from Build Settings. :)

Comment: @trishcode Even after doing this i'm getting same error(xcode12 beta4), any work arounds

Comment: @SivakrishnaPerla If you can open the project in Xcode 11, then you can see exactly which targets Valid Architectures is used on.  You could even clear the setting in Xcode 11, and then try the project again in Xcode 12.  If you still need a workaround and you're getting the error on an embedded framework, then SlashDevSlashGnoll's answer should work.  If you need a workaround and you're getting the error on a Cocoapod, then exclude the arm64 architecture in the Podfile post install.

Comment: If I remove VALID_ARCHS and add arm64 to Excluded architecture, I get this error - 

Check dependencies
No architectures to compile for (ARCHS=arm64 x86_64, VALID_ARCHS=, EXCLUDED_ARCHS=(
    arm64
)).

Comment: @nOObiOS I'm assuming after you removed Valid Archs that you tried to run without excluding arm64, and that didn't work.  Do you have Standard Architectures or some other architectures (in addition to arm64) in the Architectures build setting?

Comment: I don't have this property on my project for some reason.

Comment: @JBarros35 The VALID_ARCHS setting is not shown as of Xcode 12. You have to manually add the VALID_ARCHS setting back in as a User-Defined Setting. I included a screenshot of where to add a User-Defined build setting in my answer.

Comment: @JBarros35 Yes, you have to manually add the VALID_ARCHS setting, and you MUST NOT use arm64 in Excluded Architectures. Excluded Architectures must be empty.

Comment: I had to remove the entry from both the project and the target, actually, then it worked.

Answer (score 74):

### Hidden Gem in all these answers

I had changed "Excluded Architectures" in my target for the main project, but not for the PODS project. It is a truly hidden gem. I have been with this problem for weeks now.

[image: Excluding arm64 in PODS PROJECT]

Comment: Will this affect the build in production for some devices?

Comment: @MohamedAbdou arm64 is used for physical devices, so I assume there might be a conflict when trying to simulate it on a real iPhone. Either way, you could try it as is, and in any case, you remove arm64 as an Excluded Architecture. For actual production and release, I suggest you simulate it successfully on both physical and virtual devices and use those settings for the release.

Comment: not perfect answer either, now your project doesn't compile on M1 & simulator, because all pods are excluded

Comment: Remember to set excluded archs for the project and not the targets so that all targets inherit the excluded archs setting

Comment: Actually it will given error in production when you test it on real device. It will show error  "the developer of this App needs to be update it to work with this version of iOS". This is because as per apple "In iOS 11 and later, all apps use the 64-bit architecture"  so if you  exclude arm 64 for the main project you will not be able to open the app on real device. So to fix this  you just have to exclude the arm64 for simulator only, it will work on all the machines including M1 or M2.

Answer (score 52):

#### Easy fix

1. Right click on xcode in Applications folder
2. Get info
3. Select "Open using Rosetta"

Run.

[Xcode get info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jj508.png)

Comment: not great, now you are running Xcode on Rosetta emulator, which means your stuff runs slow

Comment: This worked for me, but (probably due to my code base) iOS 14 and 15 Simulators were not working. I had to use version 13.5.

Comment: This worked when the top-voted answer didn't.  On older machines, things ran fine; on the new MacBook, things didn't run until doing this.  If you are having issues with a newer Mac, this may be what you need, instead of excluding architectures.  See also, https://stackoverflow.com/a/69985894/7106170

Comment: It appears this no longer works as of Xcode 14.3.  I have both 14.2 and 14.3 installed at the moment.  The former has the "Open using Rosetta" option.  The latter does not.

Answer (score 52):

## Preface

When you build an app, you build it for a specific 'platform' and 'CPU Architecture' *combination*.

***iOS Platforms:***

- iOS device `"generic/platform=iOS"`
- Simulator `"generic/platform=iOS Simulator"`

<sub>**Note:** There a whole lot more platforms. For brevity I’m just focused on iOS platforms. Otherwise there are macOS, watchOS, tvOS, visionOS platforms.</sub>

***CPU Architectures:***

- arm64
- x86_64

This is because a macOS vs iOS vs iOS simulator will use different libraries. See [How does building for iOS device and simulator actually differ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10205654/how-does-building-for-ios-device-and-simulator-actually-differ/10205790#10205790)

And different CPU Architectures use different CPU instructions.

This ultimately means the built binary and the environment (device/simulator) you're running it in, will need to match. Otherwise some system libraries won't exist on the operating system, or the CPU instructions can't get processed.

### Where are these settings and who changes them?

The configuration for this is in Xcode Build Settings. They affect the flags sent to the compiler. Usually Xcode does things correct and you don’t need to make any adjustments. In certain cases it doesn’t or someone (app creator, library creator, library consumer, package manager i.e. someone who makes changes into the Podfile) has tweaked these settings in a way that things get misaligned.

### Will you always be building for one combination?

No. If you're using a `Release` config, then you'll end up archiving your product for BOTH `arm64` and `x86_64` architectures.

During the archive process (often in your CI/CD) then things will fail because the simulator architectures are selected as well.

Yet a 'Debug' builds onto your physical devices won't attempt to build for a different platform or architecture. It's because it prioritizes 'development speed' over 'complete correctness'.

The default Xcode `ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH` settings for this are:

[image]

### I have an Intel MacBook. If I don't exclude any architecture and platform, what will happen?

- If you're building a **debug** config, then it will only build for the CPU architecture of the destination's platform. Meaning:

  - If you're building into your iPhone, you'll just need to support ARM64
  - If you're building into a simulator, you'll just need to support X86_64
- If you're building a **release** config, then it will:

  - Build for **both** platforms and all possible architectures.

### I have an M1 MacBook. If I don't exclude any architecture and platform, what will happen?

- If you're building a **debug** config, then it will only build for the CPU architecture of the destination's platform. Meaning:

  - If you're building into your iPhone, you'll just need to support ARM64
  - If you're building into a simulator, you'll just need to support ARM64
  - Alternatively you can enable Rosetta for Xcode. In that case if you're building into a simulator, then you need to support X86_64 as well.
- If you're building a **release** config, then it will:

  - Build for **both** platforms and all possible architectures.

### Why is it different for Release builds?

During active development, you want to build things fast. It doesn't make sense for you to actively build architectures you don't need to use. That means if you're building into a device, then you only want to build for that platform-architecture combo. You don't want to build the other combinations.

However if you're releasing it — for others. Then because you don't want to limit/dictate how they build your app, then you have to build for all possible combinations and make sure your framework compiles for all of them.

For an app it may make less sense to make an archive for the simulator platform, however for a framework, your consumer is another developer. That developer will be building your framework into a simulator and into a real device. Hence you need to support both platforms and architectures.

### Is CocoaPods the source of the problem?

It depends. If the pod has excluded a certain architecture, and you're trying to build for that architecture, then you have to ask the pod owner to not excluded it.

Otherwise if all of your pods are supporting the given platform/architecture that you're trying to build for, then it's a problem from within the code you you wrote yourself in your host app.

## Solution

> **Update pre-compiled libraries with Apple silicon support**
>
> If the library named in the error message is from a vendor, see
> [Update pre-compiled libraries from
> vendors](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/technotes/tn3117-resolving-build-errors-for-apple-silicon#Update-pre-compiled-libraries-from-vendors). If you have source code for the library, rebuild the library as an
> XCFramework with support for the simulator on Apple silicon. To learn
> how to build an XCFramework, see [Creating a multiplatform binary
> framework
> bundle](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/Xcode/creating-a-multi-platform-binary-framework-bundle).
>
> **Update pre-compiled libraries from vendors**
>
> If the library producing the build error is a pre-compiled library
> from a vendor and you don’t have the source code, contact the vendor
> for an updated XCFramework supporting Apple silicon. If an update
> isn’t available from the vendor, temporarily use the EXCLUDED_ARCHS
> build setting to exclude arm64 for the simulator SDK as shown in the
> figure below. Do not exclude arm64 for any other SDK.
>
> From [Docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/technotes/tn3117-resolving-build-errors-for-apple-silicon)

### More Questions in regard to the outcome of the solution:

**What happens if I exclude ARM64 for the 'iOS Simulator' Platform?**

You won't be able to build into M1 simulators directly. You'd have to Use Xcode with Rosetta on M1 then. Which is a hack and is slightly slower.

**What happens if I exclude X86 for the 'iOS Simulator' Platform?**

You won't be able to build into Intel based simulators. Nor you'd be able to build into a simulator using Rosetta.

**What happens if exclude ARM64 for the 'iOS' Platform?**

You won't be able to build into physical devices. Nor archive for them.  Terrible idea!

### So I should exclude architectures?

> Strive for your app, including all of its pre-compiled libraries, to always build for the complete set of architectures defined by the default value of the ARCHS build setting. Only use the EXCLUDED_ARCHS build setting on targets where the final released app is not using the target’s functionality on a specific architecture, such as a Mac app that only supports a legacy feature on Intel-based Mac computers. Do not modify the ARCHS build setting to achieve the same result.

Additionally in big teams, some developers may be on an M1, while some others are on older Intel based MacBooks. You never know maybe some day there'd be an M5 Macbook, that will have a distinct architecture. So it's good to be considerate of how you make your project/product/framework compatible for your own devs and your library consumers.

### Do we have an iOS device with Intel X86_64?

Such a thing doesn't exist.

### How do I inspect a binary?

You can use either `lipo`, `file` or `dyld_info`.

- `lipo` and `file` only give you architecture information.
- `dyld_info` gives you architecture, platform information and more

See comparisons a simple inspection on the terminal app binary:

[image]

Remember within an XCFramework there will be usually two or more binaries. Example if we just used `lipo -info` we have to do it on both binaries of our library:

```
lipo -info <path-to-binary>
```

On the arm64 directory within an xcframework packaging,
I see:

```
Non-fat file: /Users/mfaani/Video.xcframework/ios-arm64/Video.framework/Video is architecture: arm64
```

For the sims I see:

```
Architectures in the fat file: /Users/mfaani/Video.xcframework/ios-arm64_x86_64-simulator/Video.framework/Video are: x86_64 arm64
```

You can go into your mac's /Applications, right click; 'show Package Contents' for any app; find the app's associated binary. And then inspect it using `lipo`.

To be clear, a framework or an app can both be inspected with `lipo`. Similarly if you access the build folder on the simulator, you can inspect the binary as well.

### What's the difference between an XCFramework and a FAT binary?

- A [FAT binary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fat_binary), is just a binary — with two (or more) architectures combined into a **single** binary. It's just named FAT because it's fattened. Its other names are 'multi-architecture binary' or [universal binary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_binary).
- An XCFramework is just a structured folder, a wrapper. Nothing more. That has distinct folders **per platform**. Within each folder there's a binary. That binary can be FAT binary or non-FAT (single architecture).

Also note, a FAT binary can be either a framework or the binary of an app. An XCFramework is just a framework. It's never the app itself.

### Does my app get bloated with all the other platforms-architecture combinations I don't need?

XCFramework won't bloat app store submissions, because an archive for the iOS device will just pick up each framework from a *directory that's isolated* from simulator platform.

However with FAT binaries, given that it was just a single binary, you had to *thin/slice* the dependencies before submitting to Apple store. Otherwise you'd get the following error:

> Unsupported Architecture. Your executable contains unsupported architecture '[x86_64, i386]'."

For more on that and its previous solution, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30547283/5175709)

To be perfectly clear, this was an issue in pre-xcode 12. But not every project setup would face this. You'd only face this **if** you had some pre-compiled dependency from a vendor (who didn't share their source code, but just shared the FAT binary so you can build the app for both device and sim), otherwise if you had access to the source code then your archive wouldn't contain compilations for both architectures. It would only contain binaries for targeted architecture.

Also see this great [blog post](https://blog.embrace.io/xcode-12-and-xcframework/) for about some more details and historical context.

### What does the Folder structure of a FAT look like?

It's just a binary. It's not a folder. The binary works for two or more architectures.

### What does the Folder structure of an xcframework look like?

```
ios-arm64
   - binary
ios-arm64_x86_64-simulator
   - (FAT) binary
```

If an XCFramework is made to work with mac Catalyst then the folder structure would be like:

```
ios-arm64
    - binary
ios-arm64_x86_64-simulator
    - (FAT) binary
ios-x86_64-maccatalyst
    - binary
```

For a more comprehensive list of possible platforms. See [XCFrameworsk: Demonstration of creating and integrating xcframeworks and their co-op with static libraries and Swift packages](https://github.com/bielikb/xcframeworks)

### Why doesn't my vendor support ios-arm64-simulator?

It could be for a number of reasons.

- **migration effort:** Often it's just that when the compiled they didn't have an M1, and it's been a long time since they've compiled and if they compile they have to make some changes. Like you have to understand it's been years that that there wasn't a need for a new architecture-platform combination. So this is new and not everyone understands it. The fact that Swift is now ABI compatible with its previous versions reduce the need for framework owners to recompile their app with every new Swift release. So they could go on years without the need to recompile...
- **limitation:** The pre-compiled library depends on another pre-compiled library which isn't compiled for arm64-sim.
- The owner of the framework doesn't have an Apple Silicon (arm64) machine. Or the person who knows about those stuff has left the company.

### Any last words?

Make sure you look into ALL Project AND Target AND Pod Project AND Pod Target settings. If one of them excludes a certain architecture then you can't build your app for that architecture. Often this could be in your Podfile.

Or if the pod/framework is being compiled in a totally different repo, then the settings that you have set there, are what matters the most.

If you pay attention to the error message you get, it should be easy to navigate your way to the target that doesn't support. Once you identify the target, then you have to identify when/where it gets compiled using the notes in the two paragraphs above.

Comment: `file /path/to/executable` is another option for listing the contained Instruction Set Architecture (ISA) slices.

Comment: The best explanation one could find among all the answers in here! It's always better to know about the reason of the problem instead of blindly going for some code snippets to fix. Thanks!

Answer (score 48):

**Xcode 12.3**

I solved this problem by setting Validate Workspace to Yes

[image]

Comment: This is the only solution that worked for me, however it does keep a "Target Integrity" warning in the debugger.

Comment: What is it supposed to do? Why does it work? Preferably, [update your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/65306476/edit). (But ***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today.)

Comment: The option is not showing for me, I'm on xcode 14.0.1

Comment: @Jalil Maybe look at https://developer.apple.com/documentation/technotes/tn3117-resolving-build-errors-for-apple-silicon

Answer (score 46):

After trying and searching different solutions, I think the most safest way is adding the following code at the end of the **Podfile**

```
post_install do |pi|
   pi.pods_project.targets.each do |t|
       t.build_configurations.each do |bc|
          bc.build_settings['ARCHS[sdk=iphonesimulator*]'] =  `uname -m`
       end
   end
end
```

This way you only override the iOS simulator's compiler architecture as your current cpu's architecture. Compared to others, this solution will also work on computers with **Apple Silicon**.

Answer (score 33):

For me the following setting worked:

*Build Settings* → *Excluded Architectures*.

I added "arm64" to both Release and Debug mode for the "Any iOS Simulator SDK" option.

[image]

Answer (score 30):

As of Sep 19, 2022, none of the existing answers worked for me. Most answers suggests to exclude arm64 from build settings, after this is done, it gives **fatal error: module map file not found**

What worked for me is to **open Xcode using Rosseta**,

1. **Right click on Xcode** in applications folder
2. **Get Info**
3. Check **Open using Rosetta**
4. Open Xcode
5. Open project
6. Clean build folder
7. Run project

By opening Xcode using Rosseta, no other build settings or configurations are needed.

This is probably not a long time solution, but for quickly addressing the issue. After upgrading to **MAC OS 13.5 with Xcode 14.3.1**, there is no more open with Rosseta option anymore, but you do the following to run it on Rosseta.

1. Go to “**Product**” in the menu bar
2. **Destination**
3. **Destination Architectures**
4. **Show both**
5. Pick a simulator from the device dropdown menu that has Rosseta next to it.
6. Run project.

References:

- https://medium.com/timeless/starting-react-native-project-in-apple-mac-m1-chip-system-28da0c1f2132
- https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/670006
- https://armen-mkrtchian.medium.com/run-rosetta-simulator-on-xcode-14-3-381d341364ee

Comment: I got this working as of now. There is no need to use Rosetta. It's extremely slow. Add the exclude architecture not just in the application but in the pods as well as stated in one of the replies below.

Answer (score 26):

Go to Targets section, select each target and do the following:

- Set **Build Active Architecture Only** to YES
- Add **Excluded Architectures** and set its value to **arm64** (See attached)
- Set Active scheme (on toolbar next to project name) to any iOS Simulator
- Clean Build folder from **Product** Menu and build.

[image]

Comment: Excluding arm64 conflicts with Facebook SDK. It wants arm64, and if arm64 is excluded, it says "Could not find module 'FBSDKCoreKit' for target 'x86_64-apple-ios-simulator'; found: arm64, arm64-apple-ios-simulator"

Answer (score 21):

**Xcode Version 13.2.1 and macOS Monterey 12.0.1**

Almost everybody is facing the same issue with old projects and pods after  switching to new M1 chip system.

> "in /Users//Desktop/_iOS_app/Pods/iOS/framework/(CLSInternalReport.o),
> building for iOS Simulator, but linking in object file built for iOS,
> file '/Users/y/Desktop/_iOS_app/Pods/iOS/.framework/for architecture
> arm64"

I have come to a solution which is working perfectly.

First thing first, to all the developer who are suggesting exclude arm64 for your project will work yes it will compile  but after installation when you try to open it, it will show a popup with the message, "the developer of this App needs to be update it to work with this version of iOS". This is because as per apple "In iOS 11 and later, all apps use the 64-bit architecture" and if you exclude arm64 for your project it will not open App on iOS 11 and later.

[image: App will not open in iOS 11 and later if exclude arm64 and will show this popup]

***So  instead of selecting whole project only excluded architectures for the simulator to arm64.***

Steps:
On top of project files,
Select target > build setting > architecture > excluded architecture.
now add select  "any iOS simulator SDK" and give it a value arm64.

See the image below for refrence.

[image: only select "any iOS simulator SDK" in excluded architecture instead of excluding it for whole project.]

Answer (score 19):

If you have trouble in Xcode 12 with simulators, not real device, yes you have to **remove VALID_ARCHS** settings because it's not supported anymore. Go to "builds settings", search "**VALID_ARCHS**", and **remove** the user-defined properties. Do it in **every target** you have.

Still, you may need to add a script at the bottom of your podfile to have pods compiling with the right architecture and deployment target:

```
post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings.delete 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'
      config.build_settings['ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH'] = 'NO'
     end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 18):

I solved the problem by adding "arm64" in "Excluded Architectures" for both the project target and pod target.

Xcode → *Target Project* → *Build Setting* → *Excluded Architectures* → *"arm64"

Xcode → *Pod Target* → *Build Setting* → *Excluded Architectures* → *"arm64"

Comment: for Xcode 14.3 this solution works, there is no option like VALID_ARCHS in Xcode 14.3

Answer (score 17):

I found that

1. Using Rosetta (Find Xcode in Finder > Get Info > Open using Rosetta)
2. `Build Active Architecture Only` set to `YES` for everything, in both Project and Target
3. (You might not need it, read comment below) And including this in the `podfile`:

```
post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings["ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH"] = "YES"
    end
  end
end
```

worked for me.

We had both Pods and SPM and they didn't work with any of the combinations of other answers. My colleagues all use Intel MacBooks and everything still works for them too!

Comment: The podfile code might not be necessary. I have found I no longer need it by some magic power when its absence would once make Xcode fail to build. As of today it is no longer in the podfile and everything still works, so FYI.

"Build to Active Arch only" is still set to yes for Project and Target (for my Dev builds since that's all I do as I'm not in charge of releases, but I doubt it would break much to use it for Release builds too)

Answer (score 16):

After upgrading to Xcode 12 I was still able to build for a real device, but not the simulator. The Podfile build was working only for the real device.

I deleted VALID_ARCHS under Build Settings > User-Defined and it worked! Bashing my head for some time before finding this.

Answer (score 14):

1.Add `arm64` to `Build settings` -> `Exclude Architecture` in all the targets.

[image: Xcode ScreenShoot]

2.Close Xcode and follow the steps below to open

1. Right-click on Xcode in Finder
2. Get Info
3. Open with Rosetta

Answer (score 12):

I was having issues building frameworks from the command line. My framework depends on other frameworks that were missing support for ARM-based simulators. I ended up excluding support for ARM-based simulators until I upgrade my dependencies.

I needed the `EXCLUDED_ARCHS=arm64` flag when building the framework for simulators from the command line.

```
xcodebuild archive -project [project] -scheme [scheme] -destination "generic/platform=iOS Simulator" -archivePath "archives/[scheme]-iOS-Simulator" SKIP_INSTALL=NO BUILD_LIBRARY_FOR_DISTRIBUTION=YES EXCLUDED_ARCHS=arm64
```

Comment: Same here. Key "problem" in this scenario is actually building for a generic destination via `-destination "generic/platform=iOS Simulator"`. This leads to building for all available architectures, which includes arm64 since Xcode 12.

Answer (score 11):

**Xcode 12**

Removing *`VALID_ARCH`* from **Build settings** under **User-Defined** group work for me.

[image]

Comment: Removing? Do you mean changing its value to something empty'ish?

Comment: Yeah, Remove it from the build setting. It's worked for me.

Answer (score 11):

Starting from Xcode 14.3, simply do this. Go to Product -> Destination -> Destination Architectures and select show Both. So now you can see Rosetta simulators on your destination.

[image]

Answer (score 11):

On the new Mac OS to solve the problem you should run using rosetta on Xcode

go to:

```
Xcode -> Product -> Destination -> Destination Architectures -> Show Both
```

Now you will have a rosetta simulator for all of your simulators

Run your code with one of the rosetta simulators and you are good to go

Comment: As noted in the previous editor's edit comment, please don't use frivolous emoji: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/378226/.

Answer (score 7):

I believe I found the answer.  Per the Xcode 12 beta 6 release notes:

"*The Build Settings editor no longer includes the Valid Architectures build setting (VALID_ARCHS), and its use is discouraged. Instead, there is a new Excluded Architectures build setting (EXCLUDED_ARCHS). If a project includes VALID_ARCHS, the setting is displayed in the User-Defined section of the Build Settings editor. (15145028)*"

I was able to resolve this issue by manually editing the project file (I could not figure out how to remove the item from the project file using Xcode) and removing all lines referring to VALID_ARCHS.  After that, I am able to build for the simulator fine.

Comment: Using Xcode, VALID_ARCHS is in select Project (not Target) then `Build Setting -> User-Defined". select it and delete it.

Answer (score 6):

Go to finder -> Applications -> Xcode -> Right click on Xcode -> Select open using rosetta

[image]

Comment: While this will allow you to build your project is definitely NOT advisable.  You will be running Xcode in an x86 emulated environment.  This will likely be much slower and not take advantage of your M1 processor.

Answer (score 5):

In your *xxx.framework* podspec file, add the following configuration.
Avoid a pod package that contains arm64 simulator architectures.

```
s.pod_target_xcconfig = { 'EXCLUDED_ARCHS[sdk=iphonesimulator*]' => 'arm64' }
s.user_target_xcconfig = { 'EXCLUDED_ARCHS[sdk=iphonesimulator*]' => 'arm64' }
```

Comment: If multiple pod specs use `user_target_xcconfig` and the values don't match exactly, CocoaPods will emit warnings like this `[!] Can't merge user_target_xcconfig for pod targets: [... list of pods ...]. Singular build setting EXCLUDED_ARCHS[sdk=<...>] has different values.` The podspec syntax reference says this attribute is "not recommended" https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podspec.html#user_target_xcconfig.  So please don't use `user_target_xcconfig` for this to save many developers the trouble.

Comment: not great, because user_target_xcconfig propagates to main project, and all your pods are excluded on M1 & simulator..

Answer (score 5):

After trying almost every answer to the question and reading through Apple developer forums I found only one solution worked for me.

I am building a universal framework that is consumed in a [Swift](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swift_%28Apple_programming_language%29) app. I was unable to build to the simulator without architecture errors.

In my framework project I have a *Universal Framework* task in my build phases. If this is the case for you:

- Add the following to your `xcodebuild` task inside the build phase:
  `EXCLUDED_ARCHS="arm64"`

Next you have to change the following project *Build Settings*:

- Delete the *VALID_ARCHS* user defined setting
- Set *ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH* to *YES* ***

*** If you are developing a framework and have a demo application as well, this setting has to be turned on in both projects.

Answer (score 5):

**Updates: Oct 2020**

You can simply set `arm64` only for `Debug > Simulator - iOS 14.O SDK` under Excluded Architecture.

[image]

Comment: Are you sure? Doesn't this mean it won't actually run on a machine with Apple Silicon?

Comment: On Apple Silicon it will try to build and run with Rosetta if `arm64` is excluded

Answer (score 5):

Please, **don't** forget to **clean the build folder** after you add arm64 to excluded architecture.

You can do that by going to Menu > Product > Clean Build Folder or simply Command+Shift+K.

Comment: How? By some menu command? By manually deleting files or folders? Can you elaborate? Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/66270009/edit), not here in comments (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).

Comment: @PeterMortensen Menu > Product > Clean Build Folder (Xcode 13.4.1)

Answer (score 5):

I was facing the same issue and trying to launch a React Native app on an [M1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_M1) Mac. Note that my Intel Mac with the same project worked well without this error.

What solved the problem for me was to force Xcode to open through Rosetta.

To achieve this:

Right click on Xcode in *Applications* folder* → *Get Info* → check 'Open using Rosetta' checkbox.

Comment: duplicate to 8HP8 answer

Answer (score 5):

Xcode 13.2.1, [macOS v12](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacOS_Monterey) (Monterey), target iOS 14.0, and CocoaPods 1.11.2

I had a similar issue when including `LogRocket` and/or `Plaid` -- they are `xcframework`s and work fine on my local, but they can't be built on bitrise. I'd tried all answers above:

- `EXCLUDED_ARCHS` arm64
- setting `ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH` to `YES` in Podfile
- `VALIDATE_WORKSPACE` to `YES`
- setting `ARCHS[sdk=iphonesimulator*]` to `uname -m` in Podfile

None of them works.

But by specifying a target iOS version or deleting it would work:

```
post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = '14.0'
      # OR
      config.build_settings.delete 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 5):

Please make sure to provide the code or specific error message you are encountering, as it will help in providing a more accurate solution.

Regarding the provided information, it seems like you are trying to change the `architecture` of your app. To resolve this issue, you can follow the steps below:

Step 1: Open your project and navigate to the "Build Settings" tab.

Step 2: In the "Excluded Architectures" section, select "Yes" for the "Change Release" option.

Step 3: Under the "Debug" and "Release" tabs, click the "+" button and select the `iOS simulator SDK`.

Step 4: Choose "arm64" as the architecture for both debug and release configurations.

[image]

Please note that the specific steps may vary depending on your development environment and tools. If you encounter any issues or need further assistance, feel free to provide more details for a more accurate solution.

Answer (score 4):

Issue when compiling for the simulator:

#### Building for the iOS simulator, but linking in an object file built for iOS, for architecture arm64

```
Xcode 12.1, Pod 1.9.1
```

My project structure

- Main Target
- Share Extension
- Notification service extension
- Submodule, Custom Framework
- Podfile

1. Add `arm64` to Build settings -> `Exclude Architecture` in all the targets.

   [image]
2. Removed `arm64` from `VALID_ARCHS` and added `x86_64` in all the targets.

   [image]
3. Add following code in `podfile`

   ```
   post_install do |installer|
       installer.pods_project.build_configurations.each do |config|
       config.build_settings["EXCLUDED_ARCHS[sdk=iphonesimulator*]"] = "arm64"
    end
   end
   ```
4. Did `pod update`, deleted `podfile.lock`, and did `pod install`
5. Do a clean build.

Comment: What is "Pod"? [CocoaPods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CocoaPods)?

Comment: Yes Pod means Cocoapods

Answer (score 4):

I was also experiencing the same issue with specific library that was installed through carthage.
For those who are using Carthage, as Carthage doesn't work out of the box with Xcode 12, this document will guide through a workaround that works for most cases.
Well, shortly, Carthage builds fat frameworks, which means that the framework contains binaries for all supported architectures. Until Apple Sillicon was introduced it all worked just fine, but now there is a conflict as there are duplicate architectures (arm64 for devices and arm64 for simulator). This means that Carthage cannot link architecture specific frameworks to a single fat framework.

You can follow the instruction here. [Carthage XCODE 12](https://github.com/Carthage/Carthage/blob/master/Documentation/Xcode12Workaround.md)

Then after you configure the Carthage. Put the arm64 in the "Excluded Architectures" on build settings.
[image]

Try to run your project using simulator. Simulator should run without any errors.

Answer (score 3):

The problem here are the Valid architectures in Xcode 11. Open the project in Xcode 11 and change the *Valid architectures* value to `$(ARCHS_STANDARD)` for both your project, target and Pods. Reopen the project in Xcode 12 and build.

Answer (score 3):

First, generate x86_64 for Pod projects!!!!

```
post_install do |installer|
    installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
        target.build_configurations.each do |config|
            config.build_settings['ARCHS'] = "arm64 x86_64"
        end
    end
end
```

Second, add "x86_64" for VALID_ARCHS.

[image]

<sub>I found this after trying a lot of useless answers online, and this works for me.</sub>

Comment: To add VALID_ARCHS, in Build Settings tab, click the + button in the top area, and select "Add User-Defined Setting".

Comment: My Xcode version is 12.4 and macOS is Catalina 10.15.5.

Comment: not great because VALID_ARCHS are deprecated

Answer (score 2):

I was trying to build xcFramework when I faced this issue. Nothing was helping, but I managed to resolve this with lipo and am sharing my script:

```
OUTPUT_DIR_PATH="${PROJECT_DIR}/XCFramework"

function archivePathSimulator {
    local DIR=${OUTPUT_DIR_PATH}/archives/"${1}-SIMULATOR"
    echo "${DIR}"
}

function archivePathDevice {
    local DIR=${OUTPUT_DIR_PATH}/archives/"${1}-DEVICE"
    echo "${DIR}"
}

function archive {
    echo "▸ Starts archiving the scheme: ${1} for destination: ${2};\n▸ Archive path: ${3}.xcarchive"
    xcodebuild clean archive \
    -project "${PROJECT_NAME}.xcodeproj" \
    -scheme ${1} \
    -configuration ${CONFIGURATION} \
    -destination "${2}" \
    -archivePath "${3}" \
    SKIP_INSTALL=NO \
    OBJROOT="${OBJROOT}/DependentBuilds" \
    BUILD_LIBRARY_FOR_DISTRIBUTION=YES | xcpretty
}

# Builds archive for iOS simulator & device
function buildArchive {
    SCHEME=${1}

    archive $SCHEME "generic/platform=iOS Simulator" $(archivePathSimulator $SCHEME)
    archive $SCHEME "generic/platform=iOS" $(archivePathDevice $SCHEME)
}

# Creates xc framework
function createXCFramework {
    FRAMEWORK_ARCHIVE_PATH_POSTFIX=".xcarchive/Products/Library/Frameworks"
    FRAMEWORK_SIMULATOR_DIR="$(archivePathSimulator $1)${FRAMEWORK_ARCHIVE_PATH_POSTFIX}"
    FRAMEWORK_DEVICE_DIR="$(archivePathDevice $1)${FRAMEWORK_ARCHIVE_PATH_POSTFIX}"

    echo "Removing ${FRAMEWORK_SIMULATOR_DIR}/${1}.framework/${1}"

    if lipo "${FRAMEWORK_SIMULATOR_DIR}/${1}.framework/${1}" -verify_arch "arm64"; then
        echo "Removing arm64"
        lipo -remove "arm64" -output "${FRAMEWORK_SIMULATOR_DIR}/${1}.framework/${1}" "${FRAMEWORK_SIMULATOR_DIR}/${1}.framework/${1}"
    fi

    xcodebuild -create-xcframework \
               -framework ${FRAMEWORK_SIMULATOR_DIR}/${1}.framework \
               -framework ${FRAMEWORK_DEVICE_DIR}/${1}.framework \
               -output ${OUTPUT_DIR_PATH}/xcframeworks/${1}.xcframework
}

echo "#####################"
echo "▸ Cleaning the dir: ${OUTPUT_DIR_PATH}"
rm -rf $OUTPUT_DIR_PATH

DYNAMIC_FRAMEWORK="${PROJECT_NAME}"

echo "▸ Archive $DYNAMIC_FRAMEWORK"
buildArchive ${DYNAMIC_FRAMEWORK}

echo "▸ Create $DYNAMIC_FRAMEWORK.xcframework"
createXCFramework ${DYNAMIC_FRAMEWORK}
```

Comment: What language is this script in? Where do I run it?

Comment: @Roi Mulia: It looks like [Bash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_%28Unix_shell%29) or [Z shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z_shell).

Comment: What is "lipo"?

Comment: @PeterMortensen just googling for "macos lipo" will guide you through answers, like https://ss64.com/osx/lipo.html

Answer (score 2):

In my case, the error was thrown by GTMAppAuth which I was using with Google sign in my [Flutter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flutter_(software)) project.

Solution: You have to go to that package and click *YES* in *Build Active Architecture Only*.

[image: Xcode 12, building for iOS Simulator, but linking in object file built for iOS, for architecture arm64]

Comment: How do I get to the Build Settings of the GTMAppAuth package? (I have installed with swift package manager)

Comment: @KonstantinSchubert
refer to the attached screenshot: https://drive.google.com/file/d/165gAEFXo_8btX774FgNOFVCx-QjYNO3X/view?usp=sharing

Step 1: Go to Pod (below of runner)
Step 2:  In the middle pane, look for GTMAppAuth
Step 3: click YES in Build Active Architecture Only

Answer (score 2):

In my case updating [CocoaPods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CocoaPods) helped:

1. Uninstall CocoaPods if installed:

   ```
   sudo gem uninstall cocoapods
   ```
2. Install CocoaPods:

   ```
   brew install cocoapods
   ```
3. If you have a linking error:

   ```
   brew link --overwrite cocoapods`
   ```
4. Run `pod install`

Answer (score 2):

Adding this to the end of my pod file fixed the error:

```
post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings["EXCLUDED_ARCHS[sdk=iphonesimulator*]"] = "arm64 i386"
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Time saving salution.

Go to -> Applications -> Xcode -> Right-click on Xcode -> click on Get Info -> Select open using rosetta.

Please make sure it is in your pod file remove this.
config.build_settings['ARCHS[sdk=iphonesimulator*]'] =  `uname -m`

[[image]]

if your problem is not resolved the try this also

delete all the highlighted files from your project directory and re install the pod through "pod install".

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In my case: Xcode 12

I set empty values on `EXCLUDED_ARCHS` and set `ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH` Debug = `YES` Release = `NO` [Project's Build Setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wauHC.png)

And I included this in my Podfile:

```
post_install do |installer|
    installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
        target.build_configurations.each do |config|
            config.build_settings["EXCLUDED_ARCHS[sdk=iphonesimulator*]"] = "arm64"
        end
    end
end
```

It runs on my Simulator iPhone 8 (iOS 12) and iPhone 11 Pro Max (iOS 14) and on my device iPhone 7 Plus (iOS 13.4).

Answer (score 1):

On `Build Settings` search `VALID_ARCH` then press `delete`.
This should work for me with Xcode 12.0.1

[image: VALID_ARCH on build settings]

Comment: I don't find `VALID_ARCH`, what is this?

Comment: In Build Settings tap, click the + button in the top area, and select "Add User-Defined Setting".

Comment: Can you add the "path" (series of actions) to it?

Answer (score 1):

It worked for me when I set `$(ARCHS_STANDARD)` for `VALID_ARCHS` for Debug for Any iOS Simulator SDK.
Also I have set `YES` for `ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH` for Debug.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In the below image, in *Excluded Architectures* → in debug and release tap + button → in both debug and release.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

See this tech note: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/technotes/tn3117-resolving-build-errors-for-apple-silicon
Excluding the `arm64` for the simulator should be a temporary solution.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem but then I just put these lines of codes into Podfile at the bottom:

```
post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings.delete 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'
      config.build_settings['EXCLUDED_ARCHS[sdk=iphonesimulator*]'] = 'i386 arm64'
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case:

I had four configurations (+ DebugQa and ReleaseQa). Cocoapods is used as a dependency Manager.

For DebugQa, I gathered on the device and in the simulator, and on ReleaseQa only on the device.

It helped to set BuildActiveArchitecture to "yes" in PodsProject.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was trying to run on an [watchOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WatchOS) 7 simulator in Release mode, but the iOS 14 simulator was in Debug mode.

So simply putting both simulators in Debug/Release mode solved the problem for me!

Answer (score 0):

Set the `"Build Active Architecture Only"(ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH)` build setting to yes, `xcode` is asking for arm64 because of Silicon MAC architecture which is arm64.

arm64 has been added as simulator arch in Xcode12 to support Silicon MAC.

> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator.sdk/SDKSettings.json

Comment: If it's not running on silicon Mac then surely it should know not use arm64?

Comment: @Jonathan. Yes, it should have been done like that, but currently its not.

Comment: What is "Silicon MAC"? Do you mean [Apple M1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_M1)? Or [Apple silicon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_silicon)?

Answer (score 0):

Switch *Build Configuration* back to *Debug* mode or turn on *Build Active Architecture Only* for both Debug and Release mode.

The reason is your library/framework doesn't support new simulator architecture ARM64 (run on Mac with an [Apple silicon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_silicon) processor).

Answer (score 0):

Add line "arm64" (without quotes) to path: Xcode* → *Project* → *Build settings* → *Architectures* → *Excluded architectures*.

Also, do the same for Pods. In both cases, for both debug and release fields.

**Or in detail...**

Errors mentioned here while deploying to simulator using Xcode 12 are also one of the things which have affected me. Just right-clicking on each of my projects and showing in finder, opening the .xcodeproj in Atom, then going through the .pbxproj and removing all of the VALIDARCHS settings. This was is what got it working for me.

I tried a few of the other suggestions (excluding arm64, Build Active Architecture Only) which seemed to get my build further, but ultimately leave me at another error. Having VALIDARCH settings lying around is probably the best thing to check for first.

Answer (score 0):

Only add *Any iOS Simulator SDK* → *x86_64* to *Project's Build Settings* → *VALID_ARCHS* works for me.

Xcode version: 12.1 (12A7403)

[image]

**If your project includes some frameworks that don't support x86_64.**

- You can add these framework names(`xxx.framework`) to *Target* → *Build Settings* → *Excluded Source File Names* → *Debug* → *Any iOS Simulator SDK*.
- And then modify the *Framework Search Paths* to delete the paths of these frameworks for *Debug* → *Any iOS Simulator SDK*.

These two settings can avoid Xcode to build and link these frameworks in simulator mode.

[image]

[image]

Comment: If you have remove the frame work paths how you can access the properties from framework...

Answer (score 0):

I understand the issue with arm64 and Xcode 12 and I was able to resolve build issues by excluding the arm64 architecture for iPhone Simulator or by setting ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH for Release scheme. However I still have problems to push my framework using `pod repo push`.

I found out that setting s.pod_target_xcconfig in my podspec does not apply this setting to dependencies defined in the same podspec. I can see it in the dummy App project that Cocoapods is generating during the validation. Cocoapods validation is running release scheme for simulator and this is failing when one or more dependencies doesn't exclude arm64 or is not set to build active architecture only.

A solution could be to force Cocoapods to add post install script while validating the project or let it build Debug scheme, because the Debug scheme is only building active architecture.

I ended up using Xcode 11 to release my pod to pass the validation. You can download Xcode 11 from developer.apple.com, copy it to Applications folder as Xcode11.app and switch using `sudo xcode-select --switch /Applications/Xcode11.app/Contents/Developer`. Don't forget to switch back when done.

Comment: Is "pod repo push" literal or not?

Comment: I'm pushing to custom repository, so the command is `pod repo push {repository name} {path to podspec file}`

Anyway I commented out the validation procedure in cocoapods source file as a workaround. Instead of this I am doing the validation myself by referencing the published lib in my project.

Answer (score 0):

After excluding arm64 I always got ARCHS[@]: unbound variable. For me the only solution was to add x86_64 to the target build setting as mentioned here [Problems after upgrading to Xcode 12:ld: building for iOS Simulator, but linking in dylib built for iOS, architecture arm64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63993084/problems-after-upgrading-to-xcode-12ld-building-for-ios-simulator-but-linking) You also might remove the exclude arm64 you added before.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue for the simulator/[SwiftUI](https://developer.apple.com/xcode/swiftui/) preview with the following warnings:

> ld: warning: ignoring file Pods/.../X.xcframework/ios-arm64_armv7/X.xcframework/X, missing required architecture x86_64 in file Ignoring file Pods/.../X.xcframework/ios-arm64_armv7/X.xcframework/X (2 slices)

I had **recursive path $(SRCROOT)** in the **Framework Search Path** in my project settings. After removing it, the project built without the error.

Answer (score 0):

In our case it was an error in a [Jenkins](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jenkins_%28software%29) build:

> Frameworks/release'
> xxx/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/xxx-cuytrcyjdlfetmavpdonsknoypgk/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/AppsFlyerLib.framework/AppsFlyerLib(AFSDKDevice.o),
> building for iOS, but linking in object file built for Mac Catalyst,
> file
> 'xxx/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/xxx-cuytrcyjdlfetmavpdonsknoypgk/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/AppsFlyerLib.framework/AppsFlyerLib'
> for architecture arm64

We fixed it with `sudo gem update cocoapods`.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error after switching to Macbook Pro M1 App Silicon.
Solution that worked for me:

- delete the Podfile.lock
- run pod install
  that's it.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't need to build for a simulator.

The cause for me was that I had selected an iPad under iOS Simulators in the top bar where you choose the build target - selecting a real device or just `Any iOS Device (arm64, armv7)` fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the only thing that worked for me:

Add this to debug (non-release) builds:

```
// Speed up non-production builds by building only for the currently selected architecture
ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH = YES

// For unknown reasons we need this to be able to compile for simulators in Apple Silicon macOS without Rosetta
VALID_ARCHS = arm64 armv7 arm64-ios-simulator
```

And remove all instances of customization of the `EXCLUDED_ARCHS` setting for all configs (debug and release), including the infamous `EXCLUDED_ARCHS[sdk=iphonesimulator*] = arm64` one.

These were the tests I ran after making those changes, and everything passed, on native Apple Silicon (Xcode without Rosetta mode):

|  | Debug | Staging | Release |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Build & Run on Device | ✅ | ✅ | ✅ |
| Build & Run on Simulator | ✅ | ✅ | ✅ |
| Archive | ✅ | ✅ | ✅ |
| Validated against App Store Connect | N/A | N/A | ✅ |

Answer (score 0):

I've seen quite a bit of weird behavior with frameworks, I think due to changes to the simulators to support Apple silicon. My temporary workaround is, in my app/extension targets, to add `"arm64"` to the `Excluded Architectures build setting` when building for the simulator (as your preview appears to be trying to do), and setting `"Build Active Architecture Only"` to `No` for all schemes. Might be worth a try.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue I just set `Enable Bitcode` to `No`.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

When I encounter this error, I use a 2 years ago c static lib with Xcode 14.
When I achieve with the choose "Any iOS Device(64)" and connect a iPhone 14, this error pop up.
But when I connect iPhone 12, this error gone.

The root cause is the c static lib is too old and can't support iPhone 14, even it supports arm64 and you can use lipo to check which architecture a lib supported.

After I ask lib provider to download the newest Xcode and build a new release, this issue has been resolved.

Answer (score 0):

For me non of the solutions worked...

I use Xcode 14

What worked was - deintegrating Cocopods, cleaning the cache, and installing it again

In the project directory run

1. pod deintegrate ProjectName.xcodeproj
2. then run pod cache clean --all
3. then pod install

After cleaning and building again it worked

Answer (score -1):

In my case it's working 100%. Try this:

I have a temporary solution.

You just follow the image.

- Double click *architecture* and select *Other* and *Remove all lines*
- Add two things `arm7s and arm7`
- Run your physical device on the iPhone, not the simulator
- Enjoy...

[image: Example image]

Answer (score -1):

Now we just need and this to `Podfile`, to avoid cocoapods build `arm64` link file, tested for `Xcode 15` with `Flutter 3`.

```
post_install do |installer|
    installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
        target.build_configurations.each do |config|
            config.build_settings["EXCLUDED_ARCHS[sdk=iphonesimulator*]"] = "arm64"
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: Please do not post duplicate answers. There are already a few answers that show this same solution.