# Illegal Instruction 4 error while running the unit tests on Xcode

Tags: swift, xcode12, carthage

I recently updated to Xcode 12.3 and did the workaround to run the carthage dependencies. The build is fine but when I run the tests, I get the Illegal Instruction 4 error. I assume that the arm architecture issue causes that issue. I use Quick and Nimble coming from carthage and these are used in testing. I have tried setting the excluding archs and validate archs to yes but none of them worked.

I cannot move the libraries from carthage to pods or spm because there are so many configurations  in the libraries. Updating to a new Xcode version is such a pain especially if you are using carthage.

**UPDATE:**

I downloaded the carthage version of 0.37 and implemented the xcframeworks into the project. To run the dependencies for xcframeworks, I run the following command:

```
carthage bootstrap --use-xcframeworks --no-use-binaries --platform ios
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can use Carthage 0.37.0 and are able to use XCFrameworks, then [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66108441/971329) might be valuable for you  In this vesion they added support for XCFrameworks and I find it quite nice to use. Especially since this popular workaround can finally be removed again.

Comment: thank you for your reply. I tried the new carthage version and now I get exit code 65 error on one of my dependencies. what am I doing wrong?

Comment: can you provide the full output of carthage pls?

Comment: This is the error I get. The library I call is a custom sdk of mine.
"Task failed with exit code 65: -sdk iphoneos ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=NO CODE_SIGNING_REQUIRED=NO CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY= CARTHAGE=YES archive VALIDATE_WORKSPACE=NO -archivePath / SKIP_INSTALL=YES GCC_INSTRUMENT_PROGRAM_FLOW_ARCS=NO CLANG_ENABLE_CODE_COVERAGE=NO STRIP_INSTALLED_PRODUCT=NO (launched in MY SDK") This usually indicates that project itself failed to compile."

Comment: In the carthage output you have an xcodebuild log file. It should show you what's going wring when Carthage builds your framework. Usually this means, you have a config error in your framework.

Comment: thanks for the help. I removed the scripts for carthage and cleared the old libraries. sdk and the project worked well.