# Xcode 12, building for iOS Simulator, but linking in object file built for iOS, for architecture x86_64

Tags: ios, xcode12

There is Xcode error info:

> in FFmpeg/Classes/lib/libavcodec.a(aacencdsp.o), building for iOS
> Simulator, but linking in object file built for free standing, file
> 'FFmpeg/Classes/lib/libavcodec.a' for architecture x86_64.

My library file libavcodec.a supports x86_64, i386, arm64, armv7 arm7 and so on.

I have set below code in `Podfile`, then `pod install` but didn't work.

```rb
config.build_settings['EXCLUDED_ARCHS[sdk=iphonesimulator*]'] = 'arm64'
config.build_settings['VALID_ARCHS[sdk=iphonesimulator*]'] = 'x86_64'
```

Comment: Do you get this error from an SDK or is it from your code? I have the same error while using braintree SDK

Comment: I have the same issue with GoogleSignIn "building for iOS Simulator, but linking in object file built for iOS, file '/Volumes/.../Pods/GoogleSignIn/Frameworks/GoogleSignIn.framework/GoogleSignIn' for architecture arm64" but only when building with xcodebuild

Comment: I got the same error while using `xxx.a` static libraries. The lib architectures are `armv7 i386 x86_64 arm64`

Comment: I have the same error. How did you solve it?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, i tried this for Xcode version 12

**Change your react-native-ffmpeg version to version 0.4.4 in your package.json**

ie "react-native-ffmpeg": "0.4.4"

**Update the library**

"npm install" from your project root directory

**Cleaning react-native-ffmpeg pod caches**

cd ios

pod cache clean react-native-ffmpeg --all

**Update your pod file in [ios] folder.**

***replace*** the line containing react-native-ffmpeg with the below

pod 'react-native-ffmpeg/https-lts', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-ffmpeg'

**Installing Pod**

cd ios

pod install

**Cleaning your app build folder.**

Open your project in Xcode and press (⇧⌘K) to clean your build before.
OR -> in Xcode go to (Product => Clean build folder).

✅ Now run your app from Xcode.

Reference: https://github.com/tanersener/react-native-ffmpeg/issues/196#issuecomment-700935317
*Salehjarad comment*

Answer (score -1):

Put this at the end of the Podfile:

```
post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.build_configurations.each do |config|
    config.build_settings[‘EXCLUDED_ARCHS[sdk=iphonesimulator*]’] = ‘arm64’
```

config.build_settings['VALID_ARCHS[sdk=iphonesimulator*]'] = 'x86_64'
end
end

Basically you may have to do:

1. Main project target
2. Pod project target

Comment: Thx for your answer. However, it didn't work. My problem is `for architecture x86_64`, not arm64. I have done this as same as you say before.

Answer (score -1):

I think you will find your answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/63955114/2864316

Basically you need to exclude the arm64 architecture from simulator builds. You can do this manually, or change your pod file as detailed in the linked answer.

At least that answer fixed my issue

Comment: I had read this question, but it no help for me,  before.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue. I use react-native, but react-native-ffmpeg depend on mobile-ffmpeg. Solution for me was to use the LTS version of package.