# Tl.xcodeproj The linked framework 'Pods_Tl.framework' is missing one or more architectures required by this target: armv7

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods, xcode12, xcode-build-settings

I just updated to Xcode 12.0.1 from AppStore opened my old project and after build got an error.

Here is an image for error:
[image]

as I research on SO for a solution some answered mentioned changing architecture in the build setting and changing build active architecture only setting. so I did but that didn't help.

here the picture of the build setting architecture section:
[image]

[image]

as I mentioned I have gone through the same so question but they didn't help for that I have uploaded a screenshot of the solution I used.

Comment: Give this a try : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63607158/xcode-12-building-for-ios-simulator-but-linking-in-object-file-built-for-ios

Comment: @Joe Thanks for your reply but that solution didn't work either.

Comment: I'm on Xcode 11.7 now and the issue went away.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Just clean the build folder and build project. Doing this my issue is solved.

Or You can add armv7 to the Build Settings -> Architectures -> Excluded Architectures. This might solve the issue for some.

Comment: Cleaning the build folder solved the issue in my case. I just don't understand why the h*** everytime xcode needs to update we fall into this apple software nightmare. Sometimes the build process cost me more time than developing the app.

Comment: New Xcode version has several issues. Took me days to build my flutter app for IOS. :(

Comment: Cleaning resolved my problem. Don't know why :D

Comment: I Xcode top bar select
Product -> Clean build folder

Answer (score 8):

For me this was caused by first building the project with a specific target, then switching to "Any iOS Device". Cleaning and rebuilding did the job