# Transfer to Apple M1 Xcode shows an error "'FirebaseCore/FirebaseCore.h' file not found" and "Could not build Objective-C module 'Firebase'"

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, cocoapods, apple-m1

There is a fairly common problem in my Xcode project. I'm using Firebase and project perfectly works with Xcode 11 on Intel i5, but with Xcode 13 (Swift 5) on Apple M1 there are 2 dramatic errors:

- 'FirebaseCore/FirebaseCore.h' file not found

[image: 'FirebaseCore/FirebaseCore.h' file not found]

- Could not build Objective-C module 'Firebase'[image: Could not build Objective-C module 'Firebase']

My Pods:

[image]

So, what I tried:

1. Quite xcode
   Delete "ProjectName.xcworkspace", "Podfile.lock" and "Pods".
   Delete project's temp files located at ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData (Command + Shift + G in finder)
   Run "pod install" from terminal.
   Open "ProjectName.xcworkspace".

[Error: Could not build Objective-C module 'Firebase' with Swift 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57836042/error-could-not-build-objective-c-module-firebase-with-swift-5)

2. Adding `arm64` to `Excluded Architectures` for the main project AND for the Pods project

[image]

[image]

[Xcode 12: build Error on FIRAnalyticsConnector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64171400/xcode-12-build-error-on-firanalyticsconnector/65460729#65460729)

And many other options. But neither one is suitable for me. What should I try?

Comment: Try `pod deintegrate` and `pod update`

Comment: @PaulBeusterien thanx, but doesn't work. How do you think, is it possible that this problem exists because I used Migration Assistant for new macbook M1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. $ pod deintegrate
2. $ pod clean
3. **open the terminal with using Rosetta**
4. $ pod install

Comment: How do you "open the terminal with Rosetta"?

Comment: You  may need to use the Terminal prefix arch -x86_64 before these commans, such as "-x86_64 pod deintegrate".  Also, it looks like 'clean' is no longer a pod command.

Answer (score 3):

My friend tried this. Add this to the end of the podfile and re-install your pods. Took me and the team hours, but we eventually figured this out.

```
post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.build_configurations.each do |config|
    config.build_settings["EXCLUDED_ARCHS[sdk=iphonesimulator*]"] = "arm64"
  end
end
```

Comment: thanx, tell me please how correctly re-install cocoapods with M1?

Comment: @StanislavPutilov There are many ways to do this the way I'm doing is: 1. Delete .workspace file. 2. Delete Pods folder. 3. Delete podfile.lock and run pod install

Answer (score 2):

We were running into a similar build error using XCode 15 when building for the Simulator on Mac M1/M2s:

> Library 'FirebaseCore' not found

This was our setup

- XCode 15.0.1
- Firebase/Core (8.8.0) (see `Podfile.lock`)

Building for connected devices would compile and deploy OK.

That version of the Firebase library does not yet provide an XCFramework that supports running on both `x86_64` and `arm64` architectures and can lead to this and other build faiulures.

So in order to build and deploy to Simulators we needed to ensure that Xcode would show the Rosetta Simulator Destinations.

This can be done by using the following Xcode menu:

- `Product / Destination / Destination Architectures / Show Rosetta Destinations`

Then choosing a Rosetta simulator and building again allowed us to deploy to the Simulator destinations.

Note that earlier versions of Xcode provided an "Open using Rosetta" open in Finder, but this option was removed in Xcode 14.3

[image: Show Rosetta Destinations]

Comment: Save my day, searching for 2 days got final solution , thanks @Jadent

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue when transferring Xcode to M1 pro Mac. Though, none of the answers above was not working for me, I found out that my googleService.info plist was, for some reason, never transferred to the new Mac. I download it from firebase console and it started to work. Hoping this might be help someone.