# <FirebaseCore/FirebaseCore.h> file not found - Only in debug mode on M1 Pro Mac

Tags: xcode, firebase, react-native, apple-m1

Recently I moved from an Intel-based MacBook to a M1-based MacBook, and ever since I'm not being able to run this project, **but it fails only on debug mode.**

I get this message every time:

```
<FirebaseCore/FirebaseCore.h> file not found
```

However, on **release** mode, it compiles normally.

I've tried copying the project both directly from the old machine and from git.
**I've already tried:**

- Fully reinstalling Xcode from scratch
- Deleting Derived Data folder
- Cmd + Shift + K
- Reinstalling Pods
- "Find implicit dependencies" is checked on the Scheme settings
- I am working on the .xcworkspace and **not** on .xcodeproj
- Tried adding modular_header => true to Podfile
- Tried adding "arm64" to excluded architectures on build settings (both on the main project and on the pods project)

I'm using Mac OS Ventura (on both machines), as well as the latest Xcode (14.1)
The Firebase package is **@react-native-firebase/app v15.6.0**

Thanks

Comment: Potentially related solution here if using XCode 15 and an M1/M2: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77538450/333325

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: I've managed to run the project on debug mode by opening Xcode with **Rosetta**. It's not the solution I wanted, since it's an Apple software running on an Apple processor, but it works for now.

- Close Xcode
- Right click Xcode from the Applications folder
- Tap "See Info"
- Check "Open with Rosetta"
- Close the info window and reopen Xcode

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the following lines of code in pod file.

```
  pod 'Firebase', :modular_headers => true
  pod 'FirebaseCore', :modular_headers => true
  pod 'FirebaseCoreInternal', :modular_headers => true
  pod 'GoogleUtilities', :modular_headers => true
  $RNFirebaseAsStaticFramework = true
```

Comment: Thanks, but it did not work. Still the same error on debug mode