# Plugin paths not found while trying to compile the app Cordova 12 in XCode 15

Tags: cordova, cocoapods, cordova-plugins, xcode15, macos-sonoma

While trying to compile the cordova 12 ios app in Xcode 15 it seems all the plugins can't be found but they're correctly installed.

This is an example of a blocking error during the Xcode building process:

/platforms/ios/Pods/Firebase/CoreOnly/Sources/Firebase.h:15:9 'FirebaseCore/FirebaseCore.h' file not found

This warning appears instead when we try to add the plugin:

[!] The `appname [Debug]` target overrides the `LD_RUNPATH_SEARCH_PATHS` build setting defined in `Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-appname/Pods-appname.debug.xcconfig'. This can lead to problems with the CocoaPods installation

Everything worked fine on cordova 11 with Xcode 15
Any help?

We've just tried to uninstall and reinstall the cordova project and Cordova itself and Pods several times but we always are blocked as the plugins path can't be recognized

Comment: Are you building on an M1 or M2? If so this may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69945264/transfer-to-apple-m1-xcode-shows-an-error-firebasecore-firebasecore-h-file-no/77538450#77538450