# Xcode 12, framework build failed, cocoapods, arm64

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods, xcode12

I try to generate a framework from a podspec using [cocoapods-packager](https://github.com/CocoaPods/cocoapods-packager):

```
pod package MyCore.podspec --embedded --subspecs=SDK
```

In Xcode 11, everything is fine, but on Xcode 12 I get follow error:

> fatal error:
> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/lipo:
> Pods/build/package.a and Pods/build-sim/package.a have the same
> architectures (arm64) and can't be in the same fat output file

The solution that suggested here: [Xcode 12, building for iOS Simulator, but linking in object file built for iOS, for architecture arm64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63607158/xcode-12-building-for-ios-simulator-but-linking-in-object-file-built-for-ios) to add:

```
s.pod_target_xcconfig = { 'EXCLUDED_ARCHS[sdk=iphonesimulator*]' => 'arm64' }
s.user_target_xcconfig = { 'EXCLUDED_ARCHS[sdk=iphonesimulator*]' => 'arm64' }
```

doesn't work for me. This my be related to fact that I use dependencies? Anyone have an idea how to fix this issue?

```
Podspec: 
#
# Be sure to run `pod lib lint **.podspec' to ensure this is a
# valid spec and remove all comments before submitting the spec.
#
# Any lines starting with a # are optional, but encouraged
#
# To learn more about a Podspec see http://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podspec.html
#

Pod::Spec.new do |s|
  s.name            = "MyCore"
  s.version         = "9.1.1.2360"
  s.summary         = "A short description of ***."
  s.homepage        = "https://github.com/***/***"
  s.license         = 'Private'
  s.author          = { "***" }
  s.source          = { :git => "***", :tag => s.version.to_s }
  
  s.platform        = :ios, '10.0'
  s.requires_arc    = true
  
  s.module_name     = '***'
  s.default_subspec = 'Core'
  s.static_framework = true
  s.pod_target_xcconfig = { 'EXCLUDED_ARCHS[sdk=iphonesimulator*]' => 'arm64' }
  s.user_target_xcconfig = { 'EXCLUDED_ARCHS[sdk=iphonesimulator*]' => 'arm64' }

  s.subspec 'Core' do |ss|
      ss.source_files = 'Pod/Classes/**/*.{h,m,c}'
      ss.resources =     ['Pod/CoreData/DrivePal.{xcdatamodeld,xcmappingmodel}', 'Pod/CoreData/mapping_*.xcmappingmodel', 'Pod/Assets/**/*.{csv,storyboard}']
      ss.resource_bundle = { 
        '**Core_CoreData' => ['Pod/CoreData/DrivePal.{xcdatamodeld,xcmappingmodel}', 'Pod/CoreData/mapping_*.xcmappingmodel','Pod/Assets/**/crash*.txt'],
      }
      ss.preserve_paths = ['Pod/CoreData/*.xcdatamodeld', 'Pod/CoreData/*.xcmappingmodel']
      ss.frameworks = 'CoreLocation', 'CoreBluetooth', 'CoreMotion', 'CoreData', 'AVFoundation', 'SystemConfiguration', 'Foundation'
      ss.library = 'z'

      ss.dependency 'CocoaLumberjack', '~> 3.5.3'
      ss.dependency 'Mantle', '2.1.4'
      ss.dependency 'MTLManagedObjectAdapter', '~> 1.0.3'

      ss.dependency 'AFNetworking/Serialization', '~> 3.2.1'
      ss.dependency 'AFNetworking/Reachability', '~> 3.2.1'
      ss.dependency 'AFNetworking/NSURLSession', '~> 3.2.1'

      ss.test_spec '***CoreTests' do |core_tests|
        core_tests.source_files = 'Pod/***CoreTests/**/*.{h,m}'
        core_tests.resources = 'Pod/***CoreTests/**/*.{json,txt}'
      end
  end
  
  # Core is copy of SDK
  s.subspec 'SDK' do |sdk|
      sdk.source_files = 'Pod/Classes/**/*.{h,m,c}'
      sdk.exclude_files = ['Pod/***CoreTests/*']
      sdk.resources =     ['Pod/CoreData/DrivePal.{xcdatamodeld,xcmappingmodel}', 'Pod/CoreData/mapping_*.xcmappingmodel']
      sdk.resource_bundle = {
          '***Core_CoreData' => ['Pod/CoreData/DrivePal.{xcdatamodeld,xcmappingmodel}','Pod/CoreData/mapping_*.xcmappingmodel','Pod/Assets/**/crash*.txt'],
      }
      sdk.compiler_flags = '-DTESTING=0'
      sdk.preserve_paths = ['Pod/CoreData/*.xcdatamodeld', 'Pod/CoreData/*.xcmappingmodel']
      sdk.frameworks = 'CoreLocation', 'CoreBluetooth', 'CoreMotion', 'CoreData', 'AVFoundation', 'SystemConfiguration', 'Foundation'
      sdk.library = 'z'
      
      sdk.dependency 'CocoaLumberjack', '~> 3.5.3'
      sdk.dependency 'Mantle', '2.1.4'
      sdk.dependency 'MTLManagedObjectAdapter', '~> 1.0.3'

      sdk.dependency 'AFNetworking/Serialization', '~> 3.2.1'
      sdk.dependency 'AFNetworking/Reachability', '~> 3.2.1'
      sdk.dependency 'AFNetworking/NSURLSession', '~> 3.2.1'

      sdk.pod_target_xcconfig = { 'EXCLUDED_ARCHS[sdk=iphonesimulator*]' => 'arm64', 'ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH' => 'YES' }
      sdk.user_target_xcconfig = { 'EXCLUDED_ARCHS[sdk=iphonesimulator*]' => 'arm64','ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH' => 'YES' }

      sdk.public_header_files = [****]
    end

end
```

Update:
if I add `--exclude-deps` flag, it works, but my framework doesn't include dependencies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by modifying the local cocoapods-packager source ruby code.
Modified .rb file's path:

> /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-packager-1.5.0/lib/cocoapods-packager/pod_utils.rb  (path may be different /Users/*USER*/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/cocoapods-packager-1.5.0/lib/cocoapods-packager/pod_utils.rb)

```
unless static_installer.nil?
  static_installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings['CLANG_MODULES_AUTOLINK'] = 'NO'
      config.build_settings['GCC_GENERATE_DEBUGGING_SYMBOLS'] = 'NO'
      config.build_settings['EXCLUDED_ARCHS[sdk=iphonesimulator*]'] = 'arm64' // <-- inserted here
    end
  end
  static_installer.pods_project.save
end
```

Comment: I don't think editing the Cocoapods source code is really a viable solution, why not just add the following to the end of your Podfile 

```post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings['CLANG_MODULES_AUTOLINK'] = 'NO'
      config.build_settings['GCC_GENERATE_DEBUGGING_SYMBOLS'] = 'NO'      
      config.build_settings["EXCLUDED_ARCHS[sdk=iphonesimulator*]"] = "arm64"
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: It was a viable solution. As it pointed out, that the config needs to be adjusted as shown. Thanks for that.