# Framework build failed with cocoapod pod lib lint with xcode 12.0

Tags: ios, xcode, frameworks, cocoapods, xcode12

I try to update a existing pod, but when I did pod trunk push NAME.podspec, I got this error :
[image]

I try several solution from this post [Xcode 12, building for iOS Simulator, but linking in object file built for iOS, for architecture arm64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63607158/xcode-12-building-for-ios-simulator-but-linking-in-object-file-built-for-ios/64139830#_)_ but none worked(excluded architecture, only active arch).

There is no problem when I run the compilatiton on Xcode, my framework is well generated. The only problem is when I try to pod trunk, or pod lib lint

In my xcode project, In build phase, I run that script :

```
xcodebuild -target "${​TARGET_NAME}​" -configuration ${​CONFIGURATION}​ -sdk iphonesimulator -arch x86_64 -arch i386 ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=NO EXCLUDED_ARCHS="arm64" BUILD_DIR="${​BUILD_DIR}​" BUILD_ROOT="${​BUILD_ROOT}" clean build
```

If I put ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=TRUE, the error message is a bit different :

[image]

Comment: I think I'm having the same problem with updating my cocoapod and running 'pod lib lint'. Did you ever figure out the problem, and do you remember it? :)

Comment: I'm not 100% sur of the solution, but I know I modified some thing :
my podspec, by adding this :   
s.user_target_xcconfig = { 'EXCLUDED_ARCHS[sdk=iphonesimulator*]' => 'arm64' }
s.pod_target_xcconfig = { 'EXCLUDED_ARCHS[sdk=iphonesimulator*]' => 'arm64' }

and also my xcodebuild commande :

xcodebuild -target "${TARGET_NAME}" -configuration ${CONFIGURATION} 
-sdk iphonesimulator 
-arch x86_64 -arch i386 ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=NO 
EXCLUDED_ARCHS[sdk=iphonesimulator*] = arm64 BUILD_DIR="${BUILD_DIR}" 
BUILD_ROOT="${BUILD_ROOT}" 
clean build

Comment: Thanks. Our implementation is so old that we didn’t even know about changes via xcframework, so we’re reworking the build script to create one.

Answer (score 0):

I have had a similar error in the past.

Usually it indicates (using `--verbose` you can check this):

1. The Pod itself has a code compile error.
2. Your library may need some special configs, you may need to use `spec.pod_target_xcconfig` in your Podspec.
3. The target project may need special configs. This is not recommended, but you could use `user_target_xcconfig` to achieve that.

For point #3, this is usually needed when `pod lib lint` won't pass due to your target project requiring a special config (not a common case, but may be needed in special occasions - not recommended since it is not good to modify the user's project).

I hope it helps future people reading this post.