# How do I build Xcode iOS static lib for arm64 simulator?

Tags: xcode, macos, ios-simulator, arm64

When I build static lib for Xcode simulators, and select any of the device/simulator filters, they seem to all be x86.

And when I "Add Additional Simulators" they all seem to be x86 too.

My goal is to create a static lib built for arm64 simulation architecture, to run on latest model Mac with Apple silicon arm64 architecture.

Comment: Are you building this library for multiple architectures at the same time (fat binary)? If so, then this question would be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/65117197

Comment: Siguza:  No, only for simulator on late-model arm64 Mac.  A fat lib for all "flavors" would be nice, but -- as per your link -- fat lib doesn't support same arch for iOS and Mac.  So, I still don't even know how to make a "thin" lib for only arm64 simulator on Mac.