# Update Carthage: Building universal frameworks with common architectures is not possible

Tags: xcode, arm64, carthage

I am trying to update the carthage but I getting the following error.

```
.... have the same architectures (arm64) and can't be in the same fat output file

Building universal frameworks with common architectures is not possible. The device and simulator slices for "XXXX" both build for: arm64
Rebuild with --use-xcframeworks to create an xcframework bundle instead.
```

I have tried many ways but unable to resolve this issue. Clearing the Derived Data, restarting the XCode, switching to latest version of framework, set the Architecture to arm64 also and tried running the carthage again and again but there is no solution I found. I am running app on XCode 14.2. How it can be reesolved.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Build static lib for Apple Silicon mac simulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65117197/build-static-lib-for-apple-silicon-mac-simulator)