# React Native on Apple Silicon M1 - The linked library 'libPods-ProjectName.a' is missing one or more architectures required by this target: x86_64

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, ios-simulator, apple-m1

I'm trying to build a React Native project on a MacBook Pro with a M1 architecture, for iOS simulator.

The project built nicely on Intel architecture.

It also build on device and archive well on M1. But not on simulator.

I had this classical error when switching to the M1 chipset.

> in /project-folder/ios/Pods/OpenSSL-Universal/ios/lib/libcrypto.a(cryptlib.o), building for iOS Simulator, but linking in object file built for iOS, file '/project-folder/ios/Pods/OpenSSL-Universal/ios/lib/libcrypto.a' for architecture arm64

I added arm64 to excluded architectures.

I also added the following snippet but it also react the same way without it.

```
post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.build_configurations.each do |config|
    config.build_settings["EXCLUDED_ARCHS[sdk=iphonesimulator*]"] = "arm64"
  end
end
```

Now I have:

> /project-folder/ios/ProjectName.xcodeproj The linked library 'libPods-ProjectName.a' is missing one or more architectures required by this target: x86_64.

I tried to add x86_64 on the list of architectures of the project, with no results.

I'm building from Xcode IDE. This error message appears for all iPhones I tried: 8, 11, 12 and all targets I tried: iOS 9, 10 and 13.

Comment: Are you using any specific version of the `OpenSSL-Universal` pod? It looks like all of "i386 armv7 armv7s x86_64 arm64" slices are already included in the version 1.0.2.20 of the pod against the libcrypto library. So it could be a version conflict.

Comment: No. I think it is not linked with Open SSL, it is just that it is the first library that is called. This is an higher level issue.

Comment: The issue with open SSL is solved when excluding arm64

Comment: Great! Any idea how did it solve itself since the open SSL binary already has arm64 slice in it. So I'm really curious.

Comment: I excluded arm64 both on Pods and project but I still have the same problem. @Xiiryo have u solved it somehow? I'm on a MacBook with Apple Silicon too.

Comment: Hi, not yet solved, I run on device for the time being. But it would be nice to have the simulators to explore the aspect on the different sizes.

Answer (score 142, accepted):

I had the same issue and finally, I fixed it. There are 2 main reasons for the errors:

1. `arm64` architecture support & and Xcode 12 compatible version have not been provided by many popular third party libraries yet (like Firebase, AFNetworking, etc). Xcode 11 used to automatically translate building for arm64 for the simulator into building for `x86_64`, but now that `arm64` is a valid simulator architecture (it’s the Apple Silicon architecture), that translation no longer occurs.
2. Because the Valid Architectures build setting has been removed from Xcode 12, the Project file, opened in Xcode 12, will auto-generate a `VALID_ARCHS` macro in User-Defines, and this macro will make the build fail.

I follow all steps in this post: https://medium.com/@khushwanttanwar/xcode-12-compilation-errors-while-running-with-ios-14-simulators-5731c91326e9

Final step was updating all pods by running below command inside the project folder:

```
pod deintegrate
pod update
```

Then I exclude the `arm64` for the Simulator architecture, both from main project and the Pod project.

[image: Xcode build settings]

Clean the project (<kbd>⇧</kbd> + <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>k</kbd>) then run.

Comment: Thank you for the in-depth explanation and link out to further reading. Thorough, I understand not just the fix, but why the fix works.

Comment: This keeps not working for me, but I swear it worked on another project before. Also, for some reason the excluded-architectures in my Pods project keep getting reset. The only thing that works is launching it from a rosetta terminal.

Answer (score 31):

For me opening Xcode in Rosetta mode was what solved the problem. You may have to remove DerivedData also at:  `/Users/<username>/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData`

[image]

You can install Rosetta by running: `softwareupdate --install-rosetta`

Also it seems OS prompts you to install if trying to open an app that requires Rosetta: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT211861

Comment: This works for me too as of November 2021 with Xcode 13.1 and React Native 0.66.

Comment: Before trying anything else, do "Open using Rosetta" option.

As it is the least invasive, and works in 99% of cases.

Comment: This should be treated as the accepted answer in 2022. You should also need to enable Rosetta mode on Simulator.app

Comment: deleting DerivedData worked for me!!

Answer (score 13):

XCode 12.5 broke most of the above answers.  For those using XCode 12.5 and react-native 0.64.2, I wrote up a little guide to get things working:

https://github.com/aiba/react-native-m1/blob/main/README.md

Comment: you saved my life
in the future Xcode should fix this thing?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue on my M1 Mac and here is what I did to fix this:

1. `brew install watchman`
   if you don't have node => `brew install node`
2. `sudo arch -x86_64 gem install ffi`
3. add this code at the end of the pod file which is inside ios folder:

```
post_install do |installer|
    installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
      target.build_configurations.each do |config|
        config.build_settings["ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH"] = "NO"
      end
    end
  end
```

4. `cd ios/ && arch -x86_64 pod install`.
5. run Xcode with Rosetta.
   [image].
   You can install Rosetta by running: `softwareupdate --install-rosetta`
6. exclude architecture arm64.
   [image]
7. clean build - open xcode then press Command + Shift + K

---

8. If you're using `nvm` try to replace `NODE_BINARY=node` with the actual result of the `which node` command, which in my case looks something like this:[image]
   [image]

---

Shoutout to these answers:
[one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69294780) [two](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67549251) [three](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/31181#issuecomment-823280700)

Comment: have you tried to launch without rosetta? I can but empty project (create-react-native-app). But main project only can launch with rosetta. Want to launch without because rossetta slower. What do you think?

Answer (score 1):

I was getting this error when using run-ios command targeting a simulator. I just added below script to the post install area of Podfile, did pod install and build was successful when i ran same run-ios command targeting simulator. Using Xcode 13.2.1 for reference.

```
installer.pods_project.build_configurations.each do |config|
    config.build_settings["ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH"] = "NO"
end
```

Hope someone gets help from this.

**Edit:** I am on a M1 machine and used rosetta terminal for creating the project but all other pod install done from non-rosetta terminal. my cocoapods and ffi installations were also from rosetta terminal including brew installation as well.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, Using Xcode 13.4.1, The project's frameworks are build for device and whenever I disconnect from device, it shows me error. After connecting device and clean build and then run, does the job.