# "Undefined symbol: protocol descriptor for Swift.ExpressibleByFloatLiteral" issue while installing react native on macOS Big Sur

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, react-native, react-native-ios

I was trying to install React Native on my system, and found that it failed to install CocoaPods dependencies which is required by that template error.

`sudo arch -x86_64 gem install ffi` fixed this issue but ended up with `event-config.h" file not found` error.

I changed the changed the flipper version in pod file to `use_flipper!({'Flipper'=>'0.76.0'})` and then I reached to the error mentioned above. Any help on this issue would be appreciated.

```
node version : 15.10.0
react-native version: 0.63.4
Xcode version: 12.4
```

Error description below:

```
Showing Recent Messages

Could not find or use auto-linked library 'swiftCoreGraphics'
Could not find or use auto-linked library 'swiftUIKit'
Could not find or use auto-linked library 'swiftDarwin'
Could not find or use auto-linked library 'swiftFoundation'
Could not find or use auto-linked library 'swiftMetal'
Could not find or use auto-linked library 'swiftObjectiveC'
Could not find or use auto-linked library 'swiftCoreFoundation'
Could not find or use auto-linked library 'swiftDispatch'
Could not find or use auto-linked library 'swiftCoreImage'
Could not find or use auto-linked library 'swiftQuartzCore'
Could not find or use auto-linked library 'swiftCore'
Could not find or use auto-linked library 'swiftSwiftOnoneSupport'
Undefined symbol: protocol descriptor for Swift.ExpressibleByFloatLiteral
Undefined symbol: associated type descriptor for Swift.ExpressibleByIntegerLiteral.IntegerLiteralType

Undefined symbol: associated conformance descriptor for Swift.ExpressibleByIntegerLiteral.Swift.ExpressibleByIntegerLiteral.IntegerLiteralType: Swift._ExpressibleByBuiltinIntegerLiteral

Undefined symbol: method descriptor for Swift.ExpressibleByFloatLiteral.init(floatLiteral: A.FloatLiteralType) -> A

Undefined symbol: protocol descriptor for Swift.ExpressibleByIntegerLiteral
Undefined symbol: value witness table for Builtin.Int32
Undefined symbol: __swift_FORCE_LOAD_$_swiftCoreImage
Undefined symbol: associated type descriptor for Swift.ExpressibleByFloatLiteral.FloatLiteralType
Undefined symbol: __swift_FORCE_LOAD_$_swiftQuartzCore
Undefined symbol: __swift_FORCE_LOAD_$_swiftDispatch
Undefined symbol: method descriptor for Swift.ExpressibleByIntegerLiteral.init(integerLiteral: A.IntegerLiteralType) -> A
Undefined symbol: __swift_FORCE_LOAD_$_swiftCoreFoundation
Undefined symbol: protocol witness table for Swift.Int : Swift._ExpressibleByBuiltinIntegerLiteral in Swift
Undefined symbol: __swift_FORCE_LOAD_$_swiftObjectiveC
Undefined symbol: __swift_FORCE_LOAD_$_swiftCoreGraphics
Undefined symbol: _swift_getForeignTypeMetadata
Undefined symbol: __swift_FORCE_LOAD_$_swiftFoundation
Undefined symbol: associated conformance descriptor for Swift.ExpressibleByFloatLiteral.Swift.ExpressibleByFloatLiteral.FloatLiteralType: Swift._ExpressibleByBuiltinFloatLiteral
Undefined symbol: __swift_FORCE_LOAD_$_swiftUIKit
Undefined symbol: __swift_FORCE_LOAD_$_swiftMetal
Undefined symbol: Swift.Float.init(Swift.Double) -> Swift.Float
Undefined symbol: __swift_FORCE_LOAD_$_swiftDarwin
Undefined symbol: protocol witness table for Swift.Float : Swift._ExpressibleByBuiltinFloatLiteral in Swift
```

Comment: Any update on this?

Comment: This comment (step by step) finally helped me... maybe this will help others as well https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/31179#issuecomment-829536845

Answer (score 53):

You need to exclude architecture arm64 if you are using M1 mac.
[image: Please check this image]

Also add this code at the end of the pod file

```
post_install do |installer|
    installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
      target.build_configurations.each do |config|
        config.build_settings["ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH"] = "NO"
      end
    end
  end
```

Do pod install, Clean the build folder and restart the build it will resolve the issue.

Update: for xCode 13 use the following configurations:
if you are facing `Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code in react native xcode 13`

[image: Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code in react native xcode 13]

Comment: I didn't need to add the podfile stuff. it works like a charm!

Comment: When doing so, node fails to launch. Maybe because it's trying to launch an x86 version of. it ? Any idea? `env: node: No such file or directory`

Comment: This is to confirm that it works for XCode 13 on M1 Mac. And this should be the accepted answer.

Comment: This resolved my issue.

Comment: @NicolasBraun I'm having the same issue. DId you try to solve that ?

Comment: @AkilaDevinda, just do `brew install node` and it will be fixed.

Comment: I wonder, why do we should exclude arm64 when building on M1 Macs?

Comment: I have this issue but I don't have a Mac with M1 (have Intel chip)

Comment: @DrorBar can you please post the whole error you are facing ?

Comment: @DipanSharma It is the same as original poster. Regardless, after a couple of hours, searching and trying many suggestions, I finally managed to solve it by following step by step the following helpful comment: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/31179#issuecomment-829536845

Comment: @DrorBar glad to hear that you resolved the issue hope other people will also find the link you posted

Answer (score 7):

What really worked for me, only add this Excluded Architectures and you will be fine, if you are using a Mac with M1 of course

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I managed to resolve this issue by adding an empty swift file to the project in Xcode. This had the side effect of creating a bridging header file which (for me at least) got my project to compile.

Answer (score 2):

If you are on m1 Mac

- run `arch -x86_64 pod install` in iOS folder
- run Xcode with Rosetta
- clean build
- run again

Answer (score 1):

What ended up working for me is removing the LIBRARY_SEARCH_PATHS from Xcode...

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/31438#issuecomment-865180401

Comment: For me, I had to create a swift file using XCode and automatic the bridge file was created to, and then I removed the folowing line from the library_search_paths from `debug` and `release`:

`"$(TOOLCHAIN_DIR)/usr/lib/swift/$(PLATFORM_NAME)"
"$(TOOLCHAIN_DIR)/usr/lib/swift-5.0/$(PLATFORM_NAME)"`

and got my project to compile.

Answer (score 0):

When using Dipan Sharmas solution I couldn't build for devices or "Any iOS Device" anymore. What resolved this issue for me was just excluding arm64 for the "Any iOS Simulator SDK" instead of excluding it in the upper level. Even removing arm64 from the upper level of excluded architectures, did not get the project building again for Devices and "Any iOS Device". Had to pull an older project file from my git.
[Working "Excluded Architectures" settings on Apple Silicon M1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gSUuF.png)

Answer (score 0):

Dipan's excellent answer initially worked for but then because of forces beyond my control, I had to update a bunch of React libraries and it no longer worked.

Eventually I was able to solve this problem by removing the **two** references to

```swift
"\"$(TOOLCHAIN_DIR)/usr/lib/swift-5.0/$(PLATFORM_NAME)\""
```

in `<my project name>.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj` file. I then ran my project again and it got through the last few files.

*NOTE: In the interest of full disclosure, I don't know what the ramifications of this change will be*

Answer (score -2):

This is caused because your project contains frameworks/libraries of both Swift and Objective c.

Add a swift file(If you see Objective C files already in your project) or Objective C file(If you see Objective C files already in your project). Select the targets those give above error.

This step will ask to create a bridging header. Create bridging header
Say yes and compile and run.