# No such module Just in Xcode 12

Tags: ios, swift

The project has been implemented in Xcode 11.7 and now apple has restricted taking spa files from above Xcode 12. When trying to run the app in Xcode 12.5 the error "No Such module Just" is popping up.

Tried removing pods and installing again pod update noting is working.

[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0DFpr.png)

Comment: I have the same problem where I received the error "No module found" when ran on simulator, but works fine on mobile device.

I solved by removing arm64e from Main Project > Build Settings > User-Defined > VALID_ARCH, leaving only arm64.

Comment: Problem is not only running even while generating the .ipa file to sent to store which is not possible. 
"I solved by removing arm64e from Main Project > Build Settings > User-Defined > VALID_ARCH, leaving only arm64." I didn't find any  User-Defined in my build settings.

Comment: @DipanSharma any other approach that I can solve this issue?

Comment: Can't even move further because of this issue.

Comment: can we connect so that i can see the issue if possible?

Comment: Or I have already have answer you can refer this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66369650/undefined-symbol-protocol-descriptor-for-swift-expressiblebyfloatliteral-issu/67549251#67549251

Comment: Send me the error too like which module is not found or whatever error you are facing

Comment: Yes Please "Just" module I am getting "No Such module Just" just is a library but the support is not there now.

Comment: Didn't get you, Can you please explain ?

Comment: Yes is for that we can connect and see the issue

Comment: issue is https://github.com/dduan/Just/issues/128

Comment: What is your react native version ?

Comment: Its swift version native application

Comment: can you make sure you are opening `.xcworkspace` not `.xproject` ?

Comment: No I am using '.xcworkspace' only