# The linked framework 'Pods_Runner.framework' is missing one or more architectures required by this target: x86_64

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

I am getting the below error while building my flutter app in IOS simulator via M1 Macbook pro. I am using VS code for editing.
I have no issues with the building while building with my iPhone connected to the mac.
Any idea how to resolve this.

[image]

```
Launching lib/main.dart on IPhone 13 Simulator in debug mode...
lib/main.dart:1
Xcode build done.                                            1.5s
Failed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
    objc[10488]: Class AMSupportURLConnectionDelegate is implemented in both /usr/lib/libauthinstall.dylib (0x1ffeb6b90) and /Library/Apple/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileDevice.framework/Versions/A/MobileDevice (0x1048c42c8). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
    objc[10488]: Class AMSupportURLSession is implemented in both /usr/lib/libauthinstall.dylib (0x1ffeb6be0) and /Library/Apple/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileDevice.framework/Versions/A/MobileDevice (0x1048c4318). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
    ** BUILD FAILED **
Xcode's output:
↳
    note: Using new build system
    note: Planning
    note: Build preparation complete
    note: Building targets in dependency order
    /Users/aravindganesh/Documents/Development/myproject/ios/Runner.xcodeproj: error: The linked framework 'Pods_Runner.framework' is missing one or more architectures required by this target: x86_64. (in target 'Runner' from project 'Runner')
Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on IPhone 13 Simulator.
Exited (sigterm)
```

I am adding the x-code configuration below:

[image]

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I had the same issue on my **M1 Mac** and here is what I did to fix this:

1. `sudo arch -x86_64 gem install ffi`
2. add this code at the end of the pod file which is inside ios folder:

```
post_install do |installer|
    installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
      target.build_configurations.each do |config|
        config.build_settings["ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH"] = "NO"
      end
    end
  end
```

3. `cd ios/ && arch -x86_64 pod install`.
4. run Xcode with Rosetta.
   [image].
   You can install Rosetta by running: `softwareupdate --install-rosetta`
5. exclude architecture arm64.
   [image]
6. clean build - open xcode then press Command + Shift + K

---

7. If you're using `nvm` try to replace `NODE_BINARY=node` with the actual result of the `which node` command, which in my case looks something like this:[image]
   [image]

---

Shoutout to these answers:
[one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69294780) [two](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67549251) [three](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/31181#issuecomment-823280700)

Comment: step 2,3,4 and 5 and run works for me

Answer (score 23):

A simple `flutter clean` solved the problem for me.

Comment: Worked for me after upgrading from Flutter 3.0.0 to 3.0.1

Answer (score 18):

**Xcode 13.4**

> Target > Build Settings > Build Options > Allow Multi-Platform Builds: YES

[image]

Comment: This did the trick for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The problem is related to Xcode configurations. Go to project workspace and then open Runner target  excluded architectures and add arm64 so that you can run the app on the emulator. Your problem is closely related to this issue.

Comment: I did the changes.  Still getting the same error.

/Users/aravindganesh/Documents/Development/sydneyiskcon/ios/Runner.xcodeproj: error: The linked framework 'Pods_Runner.framework' is missing one or more architectures required by this target: x86_64. (in target 'Runner' from project 'Runner')

Comment: your problem is closely  related to the architectures that run for your emulator (excluded architectures) and the ones that you have included in the Architectures.Please check if you have $(ARCHS_STANDART) included in the Architectures. It should be so by default. Also please do some more research about the architectures included in Xcode configuration (i386, x86_64, armv7, arm64, i386) this are some of them and usually in your Excluded ones u should add Any iOS simulator SDK arm64 and i386. Hope it helps.

Comment: I have included IOS build settings in the question.

Answer (score 2):

Just run `flutter upgrade`. I solved this trouble upgrading my Flutter version from 2.8.0 to 2.10.0 and added exclude arm64 into Xcode too.

Answer (score 2):

Had the same problem, but solved.

1. You can try to add arm64 to the Build Settings -> Architectures ->
   Excluded Architectures for Any iOS Simulator SDK. It helps many of
   devs, but for me it didn't work.
2. You can Clean Build Folder (⇧ + ⌘ + K), clean DerivedData directory,
   CocoaPods caches, and restart macOS, Xcode and Simulator.
   This solution works for me.

Answer (score 1):

Got the same issue on my M1, you can solve it by doing

```
cd ios && arch -x86_64 pod install && cd ../
```

that should solve the issue :)

Answer (score 1):

I just resolved this by downgrade my flutter from 2.8.0 to 2.5.3

Answer (score 1):

Try this from `ios/`:

```
rm Podfile.lock Gemfile.lock
gem cleanup
gem update
pod install
open Runner.xcworkspace/  # Do the recommend fixes from the Xcode UI
flutter build ios
```

This usually does the trick for most of these issues for me.

Answer (score 1):

The problem appear on Xcode also.. The issue is, the IDE can't identify the correct architecture.
In Xcode open the search (command + space) and type "Xcode". Scroll below and click on "search in finder".
Then right click on your Application, in this case - right click on Xcode.app and click on "get Info".

Every application on MacM1 do have the button "Open using Rosetta" in there info. Tick the box and this will fix the issue for Xcode.

I guess the same issue will occure with multiple apps beside Xcode, perhaps on VSCode also.