# Symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64 - XCode

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, macos, arm64

I'm trying to build my react native project on a Mac Intel, but keep getting the next error:

```
Showing All Messages
Undefined symbol: _swift_stdlib_isStackAllocationSafe
```

> Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
> "_swift_stdlib_isStackAllocationSafe", referenced from:
> function signature specialization <Arg[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19213782/undefined-symbols-for-architecture-arm64?page=1&tab=scoredesc#tab-top) = Owned To Guaranteed> of function signature specialization <Arg[0] = [Closure Propagated : closure #1 (__C.SKProduct) -> Swift.Bool in closure #2 (Swift.Set<__C.SKProduct>) -> () in PurchasesCoreSwift.IntroEligibilityCalculator.checkTrialOrIntroductoryPriceEligibility(with: Foundation.Data, productIdentifiers: Swift.Set<Swift.String>, completion: (Swift.Dictionary<Swift.String, __C.NSNumber>, Swift.Optional<Swift.Error>) -> ()) -> (), Argument Types : [Swift.Set<Swift.String>]> of generic specialization <__C.SKProduct> of Swift._NativeSet.filter((A) throws -> Swift.Bool) throws -> Swift._NativeSet in libPurchasesCoreSwift.a(IntroEligibilityCalculator.o)
> ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
> clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

I have tried almost all the answers on: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19213782/undefined-symbols-for-architecture-arm64?page=1&tab=scoredesc#tab-top).

Also

```
pod deintegrate 
pod install
pod repo update
```

My react-native version:

```
"react-native": "0.64.2"
```

The Architecture of my project:
[image: Architectures]

The link binary With Libraries
[image: link binary]

**UPDATE**
I also updated the react native version to 0.67.4 but still not working.

Comment: I faced with the same issue implementing Adapty library. Just keep the link to the issue here: https://github.com/adaptyteam/AdaptySDK-React-Native/issues/20

Answer (score 14, accepted):

For react-native 0.67+: After a lot of research, I found the next solution from Vegaro:

[SOLUTION LINK](https://githublab.com/repository/issues/RevenueCat/react-native-purchases/341)

First step is to upgrade the react-native-purchases by Revenuecat package to the latest version.

Clean your pods:
[REFERENCE LINK TO PROPERLY CLEAN PODS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46428793/9749951)

Declare a pods post install process:
Add the next to your Podfile:

```js
 post_install do |installer|
    react_native_post_install(installer)
    fix_library_search_paths(installer)
  end
end

def fix_library_search_paths(installer)
  def fix_config(config)
    lib_search_paths = config.build_settings["LIBRARY_SEARCH_PATHS"]
    if lib_search_paths
      if lib_search_paths.include?("$(TOOLCHAIN_DIR)/usr/lib/swift-5.0/$(PLATFORM_NAME)") || lib_search_paths.include?("\"$(TOOLCHAIN_DIR)/usr/lib/swift-5.0/$(PLATFORM_NAME)\"")
        # $(TOOLCHAIN_DIR)/usr/lib/swift-5.0/$(PLATFORM_NAME) causes problem with Xcode 12.5 + arm64 (Apple M1)
        # since the libraries there are only built for x86_64 and i386.
        lib_search_paths.delete("$(TOOLCHAIN_DIR)/usr/lib/swift-5.0/$(PLATFORM_NAME)")
        lib_search_paths.delete("\"$(TOOLCHAIN_DIR)/usr/lib/swift-5.0/$(PLATFORM_NAME)\"")
        if !(lib_search_paths.include?("$(SDKROOT)/usr/lib/swift") || lib_search_paths.include?("\"$(SDKROOT)/usr/lib/swift\""))
          # however, $(SDKROOT)/usr/lib/swift is required, at least if user is not running CocoaPods 1.11
          lib_search_paths.insert(0, "$(SDKROOT)/usr/lib/swift")
        end
      end
    end
  end

  projects = installer.aggregate_targets
    .map{ |t| t.user_project }
    .uniq{ |p| p.path }
    .push(installer.pods_project)

  projects.each do |project|
    project.build_configurations.each do |config|
      fix_config(config)
    end
    project.native_targets.each do |target|
      target.build_configurations.each do |config|
        fix_config(config)
      end
    end
    project.save()
  end
end
```

And finally, change the Library Search Paths in the project manually (XCode).
Remove:

```
$(TOOLCHAIN_DIR)/usr/lib/swift-5.0/$(PLATFORM_NAME)
```

Add:

```
$(SDKROOT)/usr/lib/swift
```

Clean your project and run the: "Archive" build again.

Comment: The 'SOLUTION_LINK' worked for me with Expo -> RN 0.64. Only changing the pods post install script solved for me. Thank you, was struggling for some days on that.

Answer (score 8):

If it is feasible for you to do so, update your React Native version. Version 0.67 fixes this issue.

If updating is not an option, the easiest solution is to update your Library Search Paths.

Select your project in Xcode, and go to "Build Settings". Scroll down until you see "Search Paths", and finally, "Library Search Paths".
Replace `"$(TOOLCHAIN_DIR)/usr/lib/swift-5.0/$(PLATFORM_NAME)"` with `"$(SDKROOT)/usr/lib/swift"`.

[image: Library Search Paths]

Credit for this solution goes to Vegaro, who posted it [HERE](https://githublab.com/repository/issues/RevenueCat/react-native-purchases/341), along with what I'd consider to be a more invasive option if this doesn't work for you.

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar issue on my **M1 Mac** and here is what I did to fix this:

1. `brew install watchman`
   if you don't have node => `brew install node`
2. `sudo arch -x86_64 gem install ffi`
3. add this code at the end of the pod file which is inside ios folder:

```
post_install do |installer|
    installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
      target.build_configurations.each do |config|
        config.build_settings["ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH"] = "NO"
      end
    end
  end
```

4. `cd ios/ && arch -x86_64 pod install`.
5. run Xcode with Rosetta.
   [image].
   You can install Rosetta by running: `softwareupdate --install-rosetta`
6. exclude architecture arm64.
   [image]
7. clean build - open xcode then press Command + Shift + K

---

8. If you're using `nvm` try to replace `NODE_BINARY=node` with the actual result of the `which node` command, which in my case looks something like this:[image]
   [image]

---

Shoutout to these answers:
[one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69294780) [two](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67549251) [three](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/31181#issuecomment-823280700)

Comment: Using Rosetta is not a recommended long term solution if you're actually interested in resolving this problem permanently.

Comment: Hi ,
Thanks i was forgot to install watchman . Once i install it. It's working fine

Answer (score 5):

I face this error because my `React Native project version is "0.62.2" and my Xcode version is 14.3`

so, I simply update:-

**1. Updating Library Search Paths in Xcode**

You need to change Library Search Paths in Xcode:

- Remove "$(TOOLCHAIN_DIR)/usr/lib/swift-5.0/$(PLATFORM_NAME)"
- Add "$(SDKROOT)/usr/lib/swift"

[image]

**2. Adding new fix_library_search_paths feature in your Podfile**

In your podfile find `post_install` section and add one line of f`ix_library_search_paths(installer)` there and function itself. Should work after that.

```
post_install do |installer|
     flipper_post_install(installer)
   fix_library_search_paths(installer)
 end
end
 
def fix_library_search_paths(installer)
def fix_config(config)
lib_search_paths = config.build_settings["LIBRARY_SEARCH_PATHS"]
if lib_search_paths
 if lib_search_paths.include?("$(TOOLCHAIN_DIR)/usr/lib/swift-5.0/$(PLATFORM_NAME)") || lib_search_paths.include?("\"$(TOOLCHAIN_DIR)/usr/lib/swift-5.0/$(PLATFORM_NAME)\"")
   # $(TOOLCHAIN_DIR)/usr/lib/swift-5.0/$(PLATFORM_NAME) causes problem with Xcode 12.5 arm64 (Apple M1)
   # since the libraries there are only built for x86_64 and i386.
   lib_search_paths.delete("$(TOOLCHAIN_DIR)/usr/lib/swift-5.0/$(PLATFORM_NAME)")
   lib_search_paths.delete("\"$(TOOLCHAIN_DIR)/usr/lib/swift-5.0/$(PLATFORM_NAME)\"")
   if !(lib_search_paths.include?("$(SDKROOT)/usr/lib/swift") || lib_search_paths.include?("\"$(SDKROOT)/usr/lib/swift\""))
     # however, $(SDKROOT)/usr/lib/swift is required, at least if user is not running CocoaPods 1.11
     lib_search_paths.insert(0, "$(SDKROOT)/usr/lib/swift")
   end
 end
 end
 end

 projects = installer.aggregate_targets
 .map{ |t| t.user_project }
 .uniq{ |p| p.path }
 .push(installer.pods_project)

 projects.each do |project|
 project.build_configurations.each do |config|
 fix_config(config)
 end
 project.native_targets.each do |target|
 target.build_configurations.each do |config|
   fix_config(config)
 end
 end
 project.Save()
end
end
```

Also, it is said, that updating **`RN to >= 0.67`** helps.

Comment: worked like a charm! just the last command `project. Save()` is `project.save()`. wasn't necessary update to 0.67

Answer (score 2):

As a workaround downgrade to Xcode 13.2.1 works for me. On this version everything is ok.

But at the version 13.3 - I have this issue

Comment: Yes, this works for me too. I don't why this issue is in `13.3` version of Xcode.

Answer (score 0):

It works for me when I upgraded xcode to 14.1.