# How to add a architecture configurations for react native 0.63.3 ios versions on ventura OS xcode?

Tags: ios, react-native, arm64, xcode14, macos-ventura

How to add a architecture configurations for react native 0.63.3 ios versions on ventura OS xcode 14.3.1 to run app in debug mode? Currently ios swift controller(CustomProductController.swift) fails with below error and we are unable to select architecture configurations in build settings.

As this post suggest upgradation, (https://stackoverflow.com/a/76169893/16245897) but is there any other configurations to fix this issue?

Mac OS:- ventura OS

Xcode version :- Version 14.3.1 (14E300c)

React native version:- "react": "16.13.1", "react-native": "0.63.3",

iphone:- iphone14, ios version 16.2

[image]

Error Message:
*Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
"_swift_getTypeByMangledNameInContextInMetadataState", referenced from:
___swift_instantiateConcreteTypeFromMangledNameAbstract in CustomProductController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update following configuration to fix arm architecture issue

- Removed armv6 from User-defined VALID_ARCHS
- Added armv6 to Excluded Architectures