# React Native Failed to build iOS project. We ran “xcodebuild” command but it exited with error code 65. The problem is with all projects

Tags: ios, reactjs, xcode, react-native

I am getting following Error when try to run any project with React-native run-ios:

I have already tried all solutions from this and many more but nothing works.

[error Failed to build iOS project. We ran "xcodebuild" command but it exited with error code 65](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55235825/error-failed-to-build-ios-project-we-ran-xcodebuild-command-but-it-exited-wit)

error Failed to build iOS project. We ran "xcodebuild" command but it exited with error code 65. To debug build logs further, consider building your app with Xcode.app, by opening proj.xcworkspace. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.

Command line invocation:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/xcodebuild -workspace proj.xcworkspace -configuration Debug -scheme proj -destination id=13B67855-76F9-4755-A1A5-7B5AEBC6D1C5

User defaults from command line:
IDEPackageSupportUseBuiltinSCM = YES

Prepare build
warning: The Legacy Build System will be removed in a future release. You can configure the selected build system and this deprecation message in File > Workspace Settings.
=== BUILD TARGET glog OF PROJECT Pods WITH CONFIGURATION Debug ===

Check dependencies

Libtool /Users/user/Work/weber/mobile-app/proj-mobile/ios/build/Debug-iphonesimulator/glog/libglog.a normal x86_64
cd /Users/user/Work/weber/mobile-app/proj-mobile/ios/Pods
export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=10.0
export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/Apple/usr/bin:/Users/user/Library/Android/sdk/tools:/Users/user/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools"
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool -static -arch_only x86_64 -D -syslibroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator14.5.sdk -L/Users/user/Work/weber/mobile-app/proj-mobile/ios/build/Debug-iphonesimulator/glog -filelist /Users/user/Work/weber/mobile-app/proj-mobile/ios/build/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/glog.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/glog.LinkFileList -o /Users/user/Work/weber/mobile-app/proj-mobile/ios/build/Debug-iphonesimulator/glog/libglog.a

=== BUILD TARGET DoubleConversion OF PROJECT Pods WITH CONFIGURATION Debug ===
Check dependencies

Libtool /Users/user/Work/weber/mobile-app/proj-mobile/ios/build/Debug-iphonesimulator/DoubleConversion/libDoubleConversion.a normal x86_64
cd /Users/user/Work/weber/mobile-app/proj-mobile/ios/Pods
export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=10.0
export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/Apple/usr/bin:/Users/user/Library/Android/sdk/tools:/Users/user/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools"
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool -static -arch_only x86_64 -D -syslibroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator14.5.sdk -L/Users/user/Work/weber/mobile-app/proj-mobile/ios/build/Debug-iphonesimulator/DoubleConversion -filelist /Users/user/Work/weber/mobile-app/proj-mobile/ios/build/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/DoubleConversion.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/DoubleConversion.LinkFileList -o /Users/user/Work/weber/mobile-app/proj-mobile/ios/build/Debug-iphonesimulator/DoubleConversion/libDoubleConversion.a

=== BUILD AGGREGATE TARGET boost-for-react-native OF PROJECT Pods WITH CONFIGURATION Debug ===

Check dependencies

=== BUILD TARGET React-Core-AccessibilityResources OF PROJECT Pods WITH CONFIGURATION Debug ===
Check dependencies

ProcessInfoPlistFile /Users/user/Work/weber/mobile-app/proj-mobile/ios/build/Debug-iphonesimulator/React-Core/AccessibilityResources.bundle/Info.plist Target\ Support\ Files/React-Core/ResourceBundle-AccessibilityResources-React-Core-Info.plist
cd /Users/user/Work/weber/mobile-app/proj-mobile/ios/Pods
export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/Apple/usr/bin:/Users/user/Library/Android/sdk/tools:/Users/user/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools"
builtin-infoPlistUtility /Users/user/Work/weber/mobile-app/proj-mobile/ios/Pods/Target\ Support\ Files/React-Core/ResourceBundle-AccessibilityResources-React-Core-Info.plist -expandbuildsettings -format binary -platform iphonesimulator -o /Users/user/Work/weber/mobile-app/proj-mobile/ios/build/Debug-iphonesimulator/React-Core/AccessibilityResources.bundle/Info.plist

ProcessProductPackaging "" /Users/user/Work/weber/mobile-app/proj-mobile/ios/build/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/React-Core-AccessibilityResources.build/AccessibilityResources.bundle-Simulated.xcent
cd /Users/user/Work/weber/mobile-app/proj-mobile/ios/Pods
export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/Apple/usr/bin:/Users/user/Library/Android/sdk/tools:/Users/user/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools"

Comment: If you are using Apple M1, please check out this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65364886/react-native-on-apple-silicon-m1-the-linked-library-libpods-projectname-a-is

Comment: No, I have MacBook Pro with MacOS Big Sur Version 11.3 (20E232)
After this error, I upgraded my XCode to 12.5 previously it was 12. But still, the problem remains the same.

Answer (score 0):

I had different looking errors and also similar to yours given here, every time due to
'Prepare build failed, legacy build etc etc'.

I simply changed the build system to new one from legacy one and all projects ran smoothly. Try it out and let me know if it works for you too.

The setting path is : Xcode->file -> workspace settings -> build systems