# cocoapods error setting up firebase for react native

Tags: ios, react-native, firebase-authentication, cocoapods, apple-m1

I have been trying to set up firebase for my recent react native project on Macbook air m1. While doing so according to the official documentation of react native firebase here https://rnfirebase.io/, I am facing few issues.

1. First one is when I try to put `if ([FIRApp defaultApp] == nil) { [FIRApp configure]; }` in my Appdelegate.m , it gives my error `undeclared identifier 'FIRApp'` (my main issue). I looked up this error and find out that I need to update pod, that's where my second issue starts
2. When I try to update pod (I tried several ways) , it shows my following error on terminal

   > ```
   > LoadError - dlopen(/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.14.2/lib/ffi_c.bundle,
   > ```
   >
   > 0x0009): missing compatible arch in
   > /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.14.2/lib/ffi_c.bundle -
   > /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.14.2/lib/ffi_c.bundle
   > /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in
   > `require' /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in` require' /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.14.2/lib/ffi.rb:6:in
   > `rescue in <top (required)>' /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.14.2/lib/ffi.rb:3:in` <top
   > (required)>'
   > /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in
   > `require' /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in` require' /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ethon-0.12.0/lib/ethon.rb:2:in
   > `<top (required)>' /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in` require'
   > /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in
   > `require' /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/typhoeus-1.4.0/lib/typhoeus.rb:2:in` <top (required)>'
   > /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in
   > `require' /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in` require'
   > /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:440:in `download_typhoeus_impl_async' /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:372:in` download_and_save_with_retries_async'
   > /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:365:in `download_file_async' /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:338:in` download_file'
   > /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:284:in `ensure_versions_file_loaded' /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:208:in` search'
   > /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods-core/source/aggregate.rb:83:in
   > `block in search' /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods-core/source/aggregate.rb:83:in` select'
   > /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods-core/source/aggregate.rb:83:in
   > `search' /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/resolver.rb:416:in` create_set_from_sources'
   > /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/resolver.rb:385:in
   > `find_cached_set' /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/resolver.rb:360:in` specifications_for_dependency'
   > /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/resolver.rb:165:in
   > `search_for' /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/resolver.rb:274:in` block in sort_dependencies'
   > /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/resolver.rb:267:in
   > `each' /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/resolver.rb:267:in` sort_by'
   > /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/resolver.rb:267:in
   > `sort_dependencies' /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.6.6/lib/molinillo/delegates/specification_provider.rb:53:in` block in sort_dependencies'
   > /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.6.6/lib/molinillo/delegates/specification_provider.rb:70:in
   > `with_no_such_dependency_error_handling' /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.6.6/lib/molinillo/delegates/specification_provider.rb:52:in` sort_dependencies'
   > /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.6.6/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:754:in
   > `push_state_for_requirements' /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.6.6/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:746:in` require_nested_dependencies_for'
   > /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.6.6/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:729:in
   > `activate_new_spec' /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.6.6/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:686:in` attempt_to_activate'
   > /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.6.6/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:254:in
   > `process_topmost_state' /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.6.6/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:182:in` resolve'
   > /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.6.6/lib/molinillo/resolver.rb:43:in
   > `resolve' /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/resolver.rb:94:in` resolve'
   > /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:1074:in
   > `block in resolve_dependencies' /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in` section'
   > /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:1072:in
   > `resolve_dependencies' /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:124:in` analyze'
   > /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:414:in
   > `analyze' /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:239:in` block in resolve_dependencies'
   > /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in
   > `section' /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:238:in` resolve_dependencies'
   > /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:160:in
   > `install!' /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/command/install.rb:52:in` run'
   > /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/claide-1.0.3/lib/claide/command.rb:334:in
   > `run' /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:52:in` run' /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/bin/pod:55:in
   > `<top (required)>' /usr/local/bin/pod:23:in` load'
   > /usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `' ``` ――― TEMPLATE END
   > ――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――
   >
   > [!] Oh no, an error occurred.
   >
   > Search for existing GitHub issues similar to yours:
   > https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/search?q=dlopen%28%2FLibrary%2FRuby%2FGems%2F2.6.0%2Fgems%2Fffi-1.14.2%2Flib%2Fffi_c.bundle%2C+0x0009%29%3A+missing+compatible+arch+in+%2FLibrary%2FRuby%2FGems%2F2.6.0%2Fgems%2Fffi-1.14.2%2Flib%2Fffi_c.bundle+-+%2FLibrary%2FRuby%2FGems%2F2.6.0%2Fgems%2Fffi-1.14.2%2Flib%2Fffi_c.bundle&type=Issues
   >
   > If none exists, create a ticket, with the template displayed above,
   > on: https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/new
   >
   > Be sure to first read the contributing guide for details on how to
   > properly submit a ticket:
   > https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md
   >
   > Don't forget to anonymize any private data!
   >
   > Looking for related issues on cocoapods/cocoapods...
   >
   > - CocoaPods compatibility with Apple DTK (Apple Silicon)    https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/9907 [open] [88
   >   comments]    4 days ago
   > - Error running project in flutter    https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/10456 [closed] [1
   >   comment]    2 weeks ago
   > - Error when "pod updating Firebase" on Ionic 5 macbook M1 Big sur    https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/10411 [closed] [6
   >   comments]    a week ago
   >
   > and 5 more at:
   > [https://github.com/cocoapods/cocoapods/search?q=dlopen%28%2FLibrary%2FRuby%2FGems%2F2.6.0%2Fgems%2Fffi-1.14.2%2Flib%2Fffi_c.bundle%2C%200x0009%29%3A%20missing%20compatible%20arch%20in%20%2FLibrary%2FRuby%2FGems%2F2.6.0%2Fgems%2Fffi-1.14.2%2Flib%2Fffi_c.bundle%20-%20%2FLibrary%2FRuby%2FGems%2F2.6.0%2Fgems%2Fffi-1.14.2%2Flib%2Fffi_c.bundle&type=Issues&utf8=✓](https://github.com/cocoapods/cocoapods/search?q=dlopen%28%2FLibrary%2FRuby%2FGems%2F2.6.0%2Fgems%2Fffi-1.14.2%2Flib%2Fffi_c.bundle%2C%200x0009%29%3A%20missing%20compatible%20arch%20in%20%2FLibrary%2FRuby%2FGems%2F2.6.0%2Fgems%2Fffi-1.14.2%2Flib%2Fffi_c.bundle%20-%20%2FLibrary%2FRuby%2FGems%2F2.6.0%2Fgems%2Fffi-1.14.2%2Flib%2Fffi_c.bundle&type=Issues&utf8=%E2%9C%93)

> I can tell that the issue is maybe with m1 chip as I am using new mac
> with apple silicon but do not know how to get this working, My main
> objective is to run react native app with firebase auth and that is
> only possible if I setup firebase in which I am having above issue,
> I'll be more than thankful if someone can help me in this regard,
> Thanks in advance

Comment: Have a look at this for your question #2: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64901180/running-cocoapods-on-apple-silicon-m1

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
sudo gem install ffi
sudo gem install cocoapods
```

Then go to **Application** folder -> Right click on **Terminal** App -> **Get Info**

Tick **Open with Rosetta** option.
build the project now.