# Xcode throwing arm64 architecture error for Macmini with M1 chip

Tags: ios, xcode, google-places-api, razorpay, apple-silicon

I am facing some issues into XCode with Apple New Macmini with M1 chip.

Into My Application i used RazorPay so it is throwing below error even after updating pods.

> Module 'Razorpay' was created for incompatible target
> arm64-apple-ios10.0:
> /Pods/razorpay-pod/Pod/Razorpay.framework/Modules/Razorpay.swiftmodule/arm64.swiftmodule

There is an another error for GooglePlaces.framework

> building for iOS Simulator, but linking in object file built for iOS,
> file
> '/Pods/GooglePlaces/Frameworks/GooglePlaces.framework/GooglePlaces'
> for architecture arm64

I tried some possible solution available [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63607158/xcode-12-building-for-ios-simulator-but-linking-in-object-file-built-for-ios) but non of them worked for me.

I am using Xcode Version 12.4.Can someone please help me how can i fix this.
This same things working well with intel based apple machine.

Comment: did to resolve this issue ? getting same.

Comment: @salmansiddiqui Not yet.

Answer (score 2):

1. With Xcode closed (Important) Go to finder -> Applications
2. Right Click on Xcode and select "Get Info"
3. On the info panel check "Open using Rosetta"
4. Open Xcode again and build

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way I found to solve this problem for Silicon Chip Macbooks.

- Go into the project Build Settings
- Set "Build Active Architecture Only" as "Yes" for both Debug and Release options
- Clean the build folder (must)
- Run your project in Xcode and it will work.