# Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64 when building flutter project

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, build, apple-m1

I'm trying to build a flutter project from Xcode Version 12.4 for a iPhone 12 Simulator with iOS 14.4.
Everything works fine from command line by running `flutter run`.

In Xcode I met the following error code.

```
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/epsilon/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-fukggautraualohaflrpmsjaeyto/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Reachability/Reachability.framework/Reachability, building for iOS Simulator-x86_64 but attempting to link with file built for iOS Simulator-arm64
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_Reachability", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in FLTConnectivityPlugin.o
  "_kReachabilityChangedNotification", referenced from:
      -[FLTConnectivityPlugin onListenWithArguments:eventSink:] in FLTConnectivityPlugin.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
```

I already followed the solution posted here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63955114/8640235 and also others from the same post, but without success.

Later edit:
[image]

Comment: I had this issue and nothing on SO helped me. The thing that solved it for me was to back up the code, create a new flutter project, and then slowly put code back until it breaks, and hopefully it won't break. This isn't quite a solution to this so I'll just leave this as a comment.

Comment: this is not an error. this is a warning. you can ignore it

Comment: I updated the post with a screenshot.

Comment: any updates? I'm stuck with this problem as well

Comment: Still facing this issue. For me works to create a build for a real device and to publish an app as well, but the build for an emulator is not working.

Answer (score 0):

create new project with **flutter create** and migrate the code into the new project.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem. After removing the `connectivity` package from the flutter project the simulator works again as expected.