# Cannot run flutter app in iOS simulator: warning: [CP] Unable to find matching .xcframework slice in ... [Flutter]

Tags: ios, flutter, dart

I am getting this error when I run my flutter project in iOS simulator:

***warning:** [CP] Unable to find matching .xcframework slice in myProject/ios/Pods/FirebaseFirestore/FirebaseFirestore/abseil.xcframework abseil framework ios-i386_x86_64-simulator ios-x86_64-maccatalyst ios-armv7_arm64' for the current build architectures (arm64 x86_64 i386).*

***In android emulator and iOS device it's working fine.***

Comment: https://susuthapa19961227.medium.com/apple-silicon-and-the-library-incompatibility-problem-for-ios-development-8c2d875283f2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Worked for me:

```
rm ios/Podfile
```

Then upgrade your packages:

```
flutter pub upgrade
```

And update your podfile:

```
cd ios && pod update
```

Then clean and run:

```
flutter clean && flutter run
```

Comment: If you want to try that answer make sure to backup your Podfile first, it can contains necessary changes and dependencies for your project.

Answer (score 3):

In order to fix that issue I was needed to set "Build Active Architecture Only (`ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH`)" to Yes for the library. You can do that manually but changes will be lost once you re-run `pod install`.

In order to set that automatically you can make necessary changes in your ios/Podfile, here's code example:

```
post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)

    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
        config.build_settings["ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH"] = "YES"
    end

  end
end
```

This was inspired by another answer, you can find more info if you need by following that link https://stackoverflow.com/a/64139830/1078641