# M1 App Build iOS Failed Flutter - AMSupportURLConnectionDelegate Location & Geolocator Packages

Tags: ios, flutter, location

Please help, I have just paid for some development work and gotten the app back. The Developer claims they have no problem running the app. I can not get it to run on my machine. The app was running before the developer added state management via block.

It looks like package/cocoapods/Xcode error which should be resolvable using latest versions, but nothing I can do clears these errors. Every time I get close I run again and all the errors come right back. I am in an endless troubleshooting loop without resolution. I am a beginner and can not afford to pay the developer $50hr to troubleshoot why an app won't run on my computer so I am tools down and stalled until I get this issue resolved.

I have reinstalled Cocoapods.
I have tried deleting PODS file.
I have tried using an old PODS file.
I have ensured it is the right version for M1 with the ffi arch install.
I have updated my developer certificate.
Pasted Arch 86 into Xcode settings.
Set versions to the latest for deployment.
I have even wiped my Mac out completely and reinstalled ALL environments from scratch but the errors persist.
I have done flutter clean and Flutter pub get and flutter build iOS and flutter run 1000 times in the last week.
I can not get this app to build for iOS and I am losing my mind. I have been trying to get it to run for almost 2 weeks!
Developer spent an hour with me and all they asked me to do was all the stuff I have already done by searching online for known issues.
I am out of ideas. I need help to solve this.
PLEASE HELP

```
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
    objc[19329]: Class AMSupportURLConnectionDelegate is implemented in both /usr/lib/libauthinstall.dylib (0x20c172c10) and
    /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileDevice.framework/Versions/A/MobileDevice (0x1141502b8). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
    objc[19329]: Class AMSupportURLSession is implemented in both /usr/lib/libauthinstall.dylib (0x20c172c60) and
    /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileDevice.framework/Versions/A/MobileDevice (0x114150308). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
    2021-07-22 22:34:26.062 xcodebuild[19329:246509] CFURLRequestSetHTTPCookieStorageAcceptPolicy_block_invoke: no longer implemented and should not be called
    ** BUILD FAILED **


Xcode's output:
↳
    /Users/tlcf/Development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/location-4.3.0/ios/Classes/LocationPlugin.m:176:13: warning: 'UIAlertView' is deprecated:
    first deprecated in iOS 9.0 - UIAlertView is deprecated. Use UIAlertController with a preferredStyle of UIAlertControllerStyleAlert instead
    [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
                UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Location is Disabled"
                ^
    In module 'UIKit' imported from /Users/tlcf/Development/simposi-main/ios/Pods/Target Support Files/location/location-prefix.pch:2:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS14.5.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIAler
    tView.h:27:12: note: 'UIAlertView' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
    @interface UIAlertView : UIView
               ^
    /Users/tlcf/Development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/location-4.3.0/ios/Classes/LocationPlugin.m:176:48: warning: 'UIAlertView' is deprecated:
    first deprecated in iOS 9.0 - UIAlertView is deprecated. Use UIAlertController with a preferredStyle of UIAlertControllerStyleAlert instead
    [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
                UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Location is Disabled"
                                                   ^
    In module 'UIKit' imported from /Users/tlcf/Development/simposi-main/ios/Pods/Target Support Files/location/location-prefix.pch:2:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS14.5.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIAler
    tView.h:27:12: note: 'UIAlertView' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
    @interface UIAlertView : UIView
               ^
    2 warnings generated.
    /Users/tlcf/Development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/location-4.3.0/ios/Classes/LocationPlugin.m:176:13: warning: 'UIAlertView' is deprecated:
    first deprecated in iOS 9.0 - UIAlertView is deprecated. Use UIAlertController with a preferredStyle of UIAlertControllerStyleAlert instead
    [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
                UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Location is Disabled"
                ^
    In module 'UIKit' imported from /Users/tlcf/Development/simposi-main/ios/Pods/Target Support Files/location/location-prefix.pch:2:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS14.5.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIAler
    tView.h:27:12: note: 'UIAlertView' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
    @interface UIAlertView : UIView
               ^
    /Users/tlcf/Development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/location-4.3.0/ios/Classes/LocationPlugin.m:176:48: warning: 'UIAlertView' is deprecated:
    first deprecated in iOS 9.0 - UIAlertView is deprecated. Use UIAlertController with a preferredStyle of UIAlertControllerStyleAlert instead
    [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
                UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Location is Disabled"
                                                   ^
    In module 'UIKit' imported from /Users/tlcf/Development/simposi-main/ios/Pods/Target Support Files/location/location-prefix.pch:2:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS14.5.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIAler
    tView.h:27:12: note: 'UIAlertView' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
    @interface UIAlertView : UIView
               ^
    2 warnings generated.
    /Users/tlcf/Development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/geolocator-7.3.0/ios/Classes/GeolocatorPlugin.m:156:55: error: expected expression
                        openURL:options:completionHandler::[NSURL URLWithString:UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString]];
                                                          ^
    /Users/tlcf/Development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/geolocator-7.3.0/ios/Classes/GeolocatorPlugin.m:156:29: error: use of undeclared identifier
    'options'
                        openURL:options:completionHandler::[NSURL URLWithString:UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString]];
                                ^
    /Users/tlcf/Development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/geolocator-7.3.0/ios/Classes/GeolocatorPlugin.m:156:37: error: use of undeclared identifier
    'completionHandler'
                        openURL:options:completionHandler::[NSURL URLWithString:UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString]];
                                        ^
    3 errors generated.
    note: Using new build system
    note: Building targets in parallel
    note: Planning build
    note: Analyzing workspace
    note: Constructing build description
    note: Build preparation complete
    /Users/tlcf/Development/simposi-main/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of
    supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.5.99. (in target 'Flutter' from project 'Pods')


It appears that your application still contains the default signing identifier.
Try replacing 'com.example' with your signing id in Xcode:
  open ios/Runner.xcworkspace
Encountered error while building for device.
```

Comment: also you'll probably need to set each pod target manually to 9.0

Comment: Also what? Was there a previous comment that didn't take? And I did set all the pod targets. It did not solve the issue and everytime j do a flutter clean and pod update those settings disappear and j have to set them again.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Got it resolved. I went back to my last working version before I hired the Developers and it runs just fine. So I pasted their lib in.... and that errored. They looked at error and it was because I needed to paste in the intl file and then fix a couple settings in Xcode. None of us knows why it was erroring on my computer only or why pasting their lib into my last working copy worked, but it is resolved. I suspect it was a Git conflict, because of the latest update to Xcode but we really don't know why. But it is resolved.

Thank-you to those who tried to help.

Answer (score 1):

Please run the application in xCode, you will get a proper error there.

In my case it was fixed with the help of this [answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63955114/3811162)