# Error: OpenSSL on Apple Silicon: libcrypto.dylib, building for macOS-arm64 but attempting to link with file built for macOS-x86_64

Tags: c, openssl, homebrew, clion, pkg-config

I'm writing a program that uses OpenSSL. It was working correctly, then I reset/removed the CMake cache. I now get the error messages below.

I installed OpenSSL using Homebrew. I added the following to my .bash_profile:

export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@1.1/lib/pkgconfig"

I added this to the global path file at /etc/paths:

/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@1.1/bin

What are some other fixes/suggestions for debugging this issue?

Errors:

```
/Applications/CLion.app/Contents/bin/cmake/mac/bin/cmake --build /Users/stephenjje/Documents/Je/test/cmake-build-debug --target test -- -j 6
[  2%] Linking C executable test
ld: warning: ignoring file /usr/local/Cellar/openssl@1.1/1.1.1k/lib/libcrypto.dylib, building for macOS-arm64 but attempting to link with file built for macOS-x86_64
ld: warning: ignoring file /usr/local/Cellar/openssl@1.1/1.1.1k/lib/libssl.dylib, building for macOS-arm64 but attempting to link with file built for macOS-x86_64
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_ERR_print_errors_fp", referenced from:
      _http_tcpip_inbound_initialize in http_tcpip_inbound.c.o
      _http_tcpip_inbound_tls_initialize in http_tcpip_inbound.c.o
      _http_tcpip_outbound_get_url_using_string_type_tls in http_tcpip_outbound.c.o
  "_OPENSSL_init_crypto", referenced from:
      _http_tcpip_inbound_tls_initialize in http_tcpip_inbound.c.o
  "_OPENSSL_init_ssl", referenced from:
      _http_tcpip_inbound_tls_initialize in http_tcpip_inbound.c.o
  "_SSL_CIPHER_get_name", referenced from:
      _http_tcpip_inbound_initialize in http_tcpip_inbound.c.o
  "_SSL_CTX_free", referenced from:
      _http_tcpip_inbound_initialize in http_tcpip_inbound.c.o
  "_SSL_CTX_new", referenced from:
      _http_tcpip_inbound_tls_initialize in http_tcpip_inbound.c.o
      _http_tcpip_outbound_get_url_using_string_type_tls in http_tcpip_outbound.c.o
  "_SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey_file", referenced from:
      _http_tcpip_inbound_tls_initialize in http_tcpip_inbound.c.o
  "_SSL_CTX_use_certificate_file", referenced from:
      _http_tcpip_inbound_tls_initialize in http_tcpip_inbound.c.o
  "_SSL_accept", referenced from:
      _http_tcpip_inbound_initialize in http_tcpip_inbound.c.o
  "_SSL_connect", referenced from:
      _http_tcpip_outbound_get_url_using_string_type_tls in http_tcpip_outbound.c.o
  "_SSL_ctrl", referenced from:
      _http_tcpip_outbound_get_url_using_string_type_tls in http_tcpip_outbound.c.o
  "_SSL_free", referenced from:
      _http_tcpip_inbound_initialize in http_tcpip_inbound.c.o
  "_SSL_get_current_cipher", referenced from:
      _http_tcpip_inbound_initialize in http_tcpip_inbound.c.o
  "_SSL_get_peer_certificate", referenced from:
      _http_tcpip_outbound_get_url_using_string_type_tls in http_tcpip_outbound.c.o
  "_SSL_new", referenced from:
      _http_tcpip_inbound_initialize in http_tcpip_inbound.c.o
      _http_tcpip_outbound_get_url_using_string_type_tls in http_tcpip_outbound.c.o
  "_SSL_read", referenced from:
      _http_tcpip_inbound_parse_request in http_tcpip_inbound.c.o
      _http_tcpip_outbound_get_url_using_string_type_tls in http_tcpip_outbound.c.o
  "_SSL_set_fd", referenced from:
      _http_tcpip_inbound_initialize in http_tcpip_inbound.c.o
      _http_tcpip_outbound_get_url_using_string_type_tls in http_tcpip_outbound.c.o
  "_SSL_shutdown", referenced from:
      _http_tcpip_inbound_initialize in http_tcpip_inbound.c.o
  "_SSL_write", referenced from:
      _http_tcpip_inbound_send_response in http_tcpip_inbound.c.o
      _http_tcpip_outbound_request_send_type_tls in http_tcpip_outbound.c.o
  "_TLS_client_method", referenced from:
      _http_tcpip_outbound_get_url_using_string_type_tls in http_tcpip_outbound.c.o
  "_TLS_server_method", referenced from:
      _http_tcpip_inbound_tls_initialize in http_tcpip_inbound.c.o
  "_X509_free", referenced from:
      _http_tcpip_outbound_get_url_using_string_type_tls in http_tcpip_outbound.c.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
gmake[3]: *** [CMakeFiles/test.dir/build.make:680: test] Error 1
gmake[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:83: CMakeFiles/test.dir/all] Error 2
gmake[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:90: CMakeFiles/test.dir/rule] Error 2
```

Answer (score 5):

Are you using a M1 Mac? From the error output, you have Homebrew installed under `/usr/local`, which indicates you're using a x86 Mac. But `/opt/homebrew` is the installation location for M1 Mac.

My guess you're just using a x86 Mac, but you copied this `/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@1.1` thing from somewhere on the web. Your CLion tries to build for `arm64` devices. Of course it fails cause you're NOT on an arm machine at all. Change your build settings and stop building your project for `arm` but only for `x86` devices.

I don't know how to do this in CLion but there're exmaples do is in XCode. [Xcode 12, building for iOS Simulator, but linking in object file built for iOS, for architecture arm64](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63955114/5101148)

Comment: Hi. I'm using an M1.

Comment: I investigated and have two Homebrew installations: one for Intel and the other M1. OpenSSL is installed on both. How can I check that the OpenSSL installation is pointing to the right place (and is M1-compatible)?

Comment: @PeteMitchell I got it. At first there's no native ARM homebrew support in M1 Mac. Homebrew was implemented with Rosetta2 (support running x86 build on arm machine). This is where the `/usr/local/` installation on your machine comes from. Nowadays, you should migrate from Rosetta2 homebrew to native ARM homebrew and uninstall the old Rosetta2 brew. There's some guide in [homebrew discussion](https://github.com/Homebrew/discussions/discussions/707#discussioncomment-342325).