# Flutter iOS Distribution failed errors

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter

Within 7 days, I did not find a solution to this problem. All the solutions suggested in [this article did not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63607158/xcode-12-building-for-ios-simulator-but-linking-in-object-file-built-for-ios) with me

- When I want to upload a new version of my app to the Apple Store, I get this message message
  `App Store Connect Operation Error`
  `Missing 64-bit support. iOS apps submitted to the App Store must include 64-bit support and be built with the iOS 8 SDK or later. We recommend using the default "Standard Architectures" build setting for "Architectures" in Xcode, to build a single binary with both 32-bit and 64-bit support.`
  `App Store Connect Operation Error`
  `Invalid architecture: Apps that include an app extension and framework must support arm64`
  [image]
- I work on Catalina mac os
- XCode 12.4
- Flutter version 2.2.3

Note: already added `arm64` for Excluded Architectures both of `Debug & Release` under my project name also tried under project Pods
[image]

- also make `Clean Build Folder`, then make new `Build` but not work
- already make `flutter clean` then `flutter pub get`  not work
- delete `Podfile.lock & Pods`  folder then use `pod install` not work
- Set `Build Active Architecture` Only `(ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH)` to  `Yes` not work

**every time to do any solution and build an archive to send it to Distribution I get failed message**

**Is there a real solution to this problem?!**

Comment: You have *excluded* Arm64. Do you know what "excluded" means?  You definitely don't want to exclude arm64 if you want an arm64 build.

Comment: could I say it in another way .... arm64 is Architectures required ... to enable it, added it, or make it included, I must remove it from ```Build Settings``` > ```Excluded Architecture``` under my Targets project, Right?!

Comment: Right. If you exclude an architecture it won't be built.

Comment: Firstly thanks for you @Paulw11, the same problem there Is no difference between Excluded or not, same message ```App Store Connect Operation Error Missing 64-bit support. iOS apps submitted to the App Store must include 64-bit support and be built with the iOS 8 SDK or later. We recommend using the default "Standard Architectures" build setting for "Architectures" in Xcode, to build a single binary with both 32-bit and 64-bit support.``` 
``` App Store Connect Operation Error Invalid architecture: Apps that include an app extension and framework must support arm64```  strange puzzle

Comment: The message is referring to app extensions and frameworks; have you checked that all of your included app extensions or frameworks also have arm64 enabled?

Comment: Thank you for your cooperation and motivation in me in the search for a solution to the problem. It has been resolved. Thank you very much again