# Flutter iOS Xcode build throwing errors?

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, dart

I'm fairly new to Xcode and have no idea why my build failed. The following is a part of the output, the parts that I omitted are just warnings about deprecations.

```
 ld: building for iOS Simulator, but linking in object file built for iOS, file '/Users/user/Documents/GitHub/bus/ios/Pods/GoogleMaps/Maps/Frameworks/GoogleMapsCore.framework/GoogleMapsCore' for architecture arm64
    clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
    note: Using new build system
    note: Planning
    note: Build preparation complete
    note: Building targets in parallel
Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 13.
Exited (sigterm)
```

What can I do to fix this issue? I have no issues building my app in android.

Comment: This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63955114/9652169) might help you. You just need to exclude arm64 for the simulator architecture from your project and Pod project

Answer (score 0):

It works against an iOS 14.4 simulator and Google Maps appear on the app correctly.(M1 machine)

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't quite understand what you mean

Comment: if you run it in the iOS 14 simulator then you don't get the error.