# xcode build not compiling due to pods unity-iphone-framework.sh line 42 source: unbound variable

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine

Basically, I made a game on unity and then when I built it for Xcode it showed up this error after I updated the pods file and excluded the arm64 architecture, can someone please guide me on how to fix this error

I have already tried on m1 mac and an intel based mac but the same problem occurs I have reinstalled pods and also have rebuilt the project but nothing seems to work

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade all Pods to the latest version available.
Delete the "VALID_ARCHS" from build settings and user define settings

Comment: hey i dont know where these two settings are can you please tell me

Comment: see the reference https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63607158/xcode-12-building-for-ios-simulator-but-linking-in-an-object-file-built-for-io