# Building for iOS Simulator, but linking in object file built for iOS in xcode

Tags: ios, google-maps, cordova, xcode13, mac-in-cloud

System specification:
Mac-in-cloud (v 12.3.1) 8 GB.
XCODE 13.4

Few months ago we had created a project in xcode on mac-in-cloud. It was working fine and we pushed it on git then rented another mac-in-cloud to test even then project was working fine.

Now a bug come in our app so we rented another mac-in-cloud, pulled code and try to run it but getting this error:

**Building for iOS Simulator, but linking in object file built for iOS, file '/Users/user220716/Desktop/Project/[project_name]/platforms/ios/Pods/GoogleMaps/Maps/Frameworks/GoogleMaps.framework/GoogleMaps' for architecture arm64**

I tried many solutions of similar questions even some same questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69962551/building-for-ios-simulator-but-linking-in-object-file-built-for-ios) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63607158/xcode-building-for-ios-simulator-but-linking-in-an-object-file-built-for-ios-f). But problem didn't solved.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 19):

The second link in your question should be the same problem you have. The solution is basically add `arm64` to `Excluded Architecture`.

[image]

Comment: Not sure why Xcode allows editing this line as a string, you should not do that, double tap to get a pop-up.

Answer (score 7):

This is an old question,  but I ran into it while migrating from an intel based Mac to an M2 based Mac.

While there are many questions with a similar issue,  for example [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63607158/xcode-building-for-ios-simulator-but-linking-in-an-object-file-built-for-ios-f), most of those seem to be related to intel based Macs running on Xcode versions supporting Apple Silicon.

This particular question mentions GoogleMaps which is the same library I had an issue with.  During my research I found [this issue](https://github.com/googlemaps/google-maps-ios-utils/issues/355) opened on GoogleMaps that explains the issue along with some possible solutions,  which for me would have required a manual installation of the library.

[image]

I was able to resolve my issue by simply changing my Podfile to use version 8 of GoogleMaps.

```
pod 'GoogleMaps', '~>8.0'
```

Answer (score 4):

**After a hour's search below solution work for me**
[image]

**if Above one not work try this only its work for me**
go to finder -> Applications -> xcode (right click on xcode got to get info and check mark the option open using roseeta) again open the XCODE
[image]

Comment: It not work for me

Comment: phuocantd try second as i describe in 2nd image its work for me

Comment: I add
 `installer.pods_project.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings["EXCLUDED_ARCHS[sdk=iphonesimulator*]"] = "arm64"
    end`
 in Podfile and it work for me

Comment: It worked for me but what is the explanation? I mean, iOS on iPhone and the simulator on M1 Mac run on the same architecture (arm64), right? 

Why should I exclude arm64 for the simulator build? Is XCode on M1 Mac running simulators using x64 arch? 

Answer (score 0):

I made Build Active Architectures from YES to NO in the build settings for the project and then Xcode 15 asked me if I want to run with Rosetta simulators, I said "hell yea!". Then the build failed. But I switched Build Active Architectures back to YES and running it still with Rosetta worked. The issue I have is GoogleWebRTC not building in non Rosetta simulators in Xcode 15.

Answer (score 0):

After using a lot of solution nothing work for me, if add arm64 iOS archive failed and if remove arm64 then failed to run on iOS Simulator :-(

```
easy and technical solution
```

[image]