# iOS The project does not compile

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods, linker-errors, arm64

I use M1 Pro Mac, the project uses CocoaPods. After running the project it fails.

**Build Active Architecture Only**

Debug: Yes

Release: No

**Excluded Architectures**

Empty

> **error build**: In /Project/Pods/GoogleAnalytics/Libraries/libGoogleAnalytics.a(GAIUtil.o), building for iOS Simulator, but linking in object file built for iOS, file '/Project/Pods/GoogleAnalytics/Libraries/libGoogleAnalytics.a' for architecture arm64

I found this solution.
[Building for iOS Simulator, but linking in object file built for iOS in xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72529517/building-for-ios-simulator-but-linking-in-object-file-built-for-ios-in-xcode)

When I add **arm64** for all targets this error comes.

> **error build:** Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code

Excluded Architectures .plist value:

[image: Excluded Architectures .plist value]

I tried to clean Build folder and Derived data, restarted Mac and Xcode but it does not help.

Please help me to find the way to fix it. Thanks.

Comment: Please explain me why you make the question -1. I used my all day for finding the answer.

Comment: You can use one of the old version of GoogleAnalytic pods. We are using  `pod 'GoogleAnalytics' `. If not work, you can try deintegrate pod then reintegrate. But don't forget to clean cache of cocoapod libraries. Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to build phases | Embed pod frameworks

Remove any entries in the output file list.  Clean and rebuild.

Comment: Please let me know how to to do this "Remove any entries in the output file list".

Comment: Highlight your top level project in navigator and then select build phases on the right and then expand Embed pod frameworks below that.