# Flutter application doesn't build after adding google_maps_flutter as dependency because of arm64 architecture

Tags: ios, flutter, macos, google-maps, google-maps-flutter

Recently I added `google_maps_flutter` to my dependencies. After that, when I tried to run the application I get
`/ios/Pods/GoogleMaps/Maps/Frameworks/GoogleMaps.framework/GoogleMaps' for architecture arm64`.
`Could not build the application for the simulator.`
I saw some solutions where I have to exclude `arm64` from `Excluded Architectures`. Doing that, the application will start again, but everything will run very slowly.

Note: the `arm64` is excluded automatically if I delete the application from the simulator and do a fresh run.

Is there any other solutions which do not impact the performance of the simulator?

Note: I use an m2 processor for developing. Here is the `flutter doctor -v`:

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.13.5, on macOS 13.6 22G120 darwin-arm64, locale en-RO)
    • Flutter version 3.13.5 on channel stable at /Users/bratosinalexandru/flutter-env/flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision 12fccda598 (5 days ago), 2023-09-19 13:56:11 -0700
    • Engine revision bd986c5ed2
    • Dart version 3.1.2
    • DevTools version 2.25.0

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 34.0.0)
    • Android SDK at /Users/bratosinalexandru/Library/Android/sdk
    • Platform android-34, build-tools 34.0.0
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jbr/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.6+0-17.0.6b829.9-10027231)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 14.3.1)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Build 14E300c
    • CocoaPods version 1.13.0

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome

[✓] Android Studio (version 2022.3)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.6+0-17.0.6b829.9-10027231)

[✓] VS Code (version 1.82.2)
    • VS Code at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
    • Flutter extension version 3.72.0

[✓] Connected device (3 available)
    • iPhone 14 Pro Max (mobile) • A51BCADC-C30C-4EE0-A036-DB7B768A83FE • ios            • com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-16-4 (simulator)
    • macOS (desktop)            • macos                                • darwin-arm64   • macOS 13.6 22G120 darwin-arm64
    • Chrome (web)               • chrome                               • web-javascript • Google Chrome 116.0.5845.187

[✓] Network resources
    • All expected network resources are available.

• No issues found!
```

Comment: This looks like a previous question asked here and can you please check answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76501159/18422887 if it helps? They also linked a github issue there were some workaround has been provided.