# XCode on Apple M1 shows "linking in object file built for iOS" or "ld: warning: directory not found for option" or "'Framework not found"

Tags: xcode, apple-m1, build-error, object-files

I am trying to compile a "WebViewGold" ios app on an M1 processor MacBook Pro, using XCode latest (13.4.1) version.

I have greatly struggled to find a solution to those XCode error codes.

I have browsed related answers in threads like: [building for iOS Simulator, but linking in object file built for iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69962551/building-for-ios-simulator-but-linking-in-object-file-built-for-ios), https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32687105/framework-not-found-in-xcode,https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9458739/ld-warning-directory-not-found-for-option.

Nothing mentioned in the above answers worked!

Any idea about what I should do?

Answer (score 1):

There is a possible, very [simple solution provided by this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69985894/2634351).

Basically, freshly upgraded versions of XCode (for example, 13.4.1) running on Apple Silicon-powered Macs (like my M1 MacBook Pro), have components that cannot properly use/output the appropriate object files in all the output platform combinations you need.

This leads to some "interesting" issues and error message cross-overs that find "almost correct" answers on StackOverflow. Hence the many suggestions to exclude "arm64" platform and similar from the build options.

The simple answer to all of that is... to just run XCode with Rosetta enabled. Rosetta will engage with the components that miss the needed cross-platform capabilities.

Here is an example of how to enable an application to use Rosetta.
You select the app icon, then go to the File menu and select "Get Info".
Then click the "Open using Rosetta" checkbox.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ryRx.jpg]

Answer (score 1):

It does seem that Build Active Architectures Only = NO is the issue, at least in Debug mode. I can successfully produce a Release archive, so I'd suggest just leaving it alone unless you're trying to debug the Intel version. Try a library, as you can ship the binary that way.