# Will react native iOS app run on Apple M1?

Tags: ios, react-native

Not whether the app will run in the iOS emulator. I couldn't find the answer to this after googling. Will a react native app which works on iOS and android work on an M1 Mac? I have an intel Mac so I can't test this.

Comment: you may need to add small changes to the project for m1 chips. I am also using m1 and I am able to get build both device and simulator.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, no reason not to. Even some people have further [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70197724/react-native-exclude-arm64-architecture-on-m1-machines)