# Flutter - google_sign_in building for iOS Simulator-x86_64 but attempting to link with file built for iOS Simulator-arm64

Tags: flutter, dart, firebase-authentication, google-signin, apple-m1

I'm trying to run my `auth-sample` project with the `google_sign_in` flutter plugin, but it won't compile.

This is the error I am facing:

```
Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone 12 in debug mode...
Running pod install...
Running Xcode build...
Xcode build done.                                           10.9s
Failed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
    objc[43499]: Class AMSupportURLConnectionDelegate is implemented in both /usr/lib/libauthinstall.dylib (0x1fafd6b90) and /Library/Apple/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileDevice.framework/Versions/A/MobileDevice (0x1066b82c8). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
    objc[43499]: Class AMSupportURLSession is implemented in both /usr/lib/libauthinstall.dylib (0x1fafd6be0) and /Library/Apple/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileDevice.framework/Versions/A/MobileDevice (0x1066b8318). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
    ** BUILD FAILED **


Xcode's output:
↳
    ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/myuser/Projects/test/auth_sample/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/AppAuth/AppAuth.framework/AppAuth, building for iOS Simulator-x86_64 but attempting to link with file built for iOS Simulator-arm64
    ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/myuser/Projects/test/auth_sample/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/PromisesObjC/FBLPromises.framework/FBLPromises, building for iOS Simulator-x86_64 but attempting to link with file built for iOS Simulator-arm64
    ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/myuser/Projects/test/auth_sample/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/FirebaseAuth/FirebaseAuth.framework/FirebaseAuth, building for iOS Simulator-x86_64 but attempting to link with file built for iOS Simulator-arm64
    ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/myuser/Projects/test/auth_sample/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/FirebaseCore/FirebaseCore.framework/FirebaseCore, building for iOS Simulator-x86_64 but attempting to link with file built for iOS Simulator-arm64
    ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/myuser/Projects/test/auth_sample/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/FirebaseCoreDiagnostics/FirebaseCoreDiagnostics.framework/FirebaseCoreDiagnostics, building for iOS Simulator-x86_64 but attempting to link with file built for iOS Simulator-arm64
    ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/myuser/Projects/test/auth_sample/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/GTMSessionFetcher/GTMSessionFetcher.framework/GTMSessionFetcher, building for iOS Simulator-x86_64 but attempting to link with file built for iOS Simulator-arm64
    ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/myuser/Projects/test/auth_sample/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/GTMAppAuth/GTMAppAuth.framework/GTMAppAuth, building for iOS Simulator-x86_64 but attempting to link with file built for iOS Simulator-arm64
    ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/myuser/Projects/test/auth_sample/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/GoogleDataTransport/GoogleDataTransport.framework/GoogleDataTransport, building for iOS Simulator-x86_64 but attempting to link with file built for iOS Simulator-arm64
    ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/myuser/Projects/test/auth_sample/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/GoogleUtilities/GoogleUtilities.framework/GoogleUtilities, building for iOS Simulator-x86_64 but attempting to link with file built for iOS Simulator-arm64
    ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/myuser/Projects/test/auth_sample/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/firebase_auth/firebase_auth.framework/firebase_auth, building for iOS Simulator-x86_64 but attempting to link with file built for iOS Simulator-arm64
    ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/myuser/Projects/test/auth_sample/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/firebase_core/firebase_core.framework/firebase_core, building for iOS Simulator-x86_64 but attempting to link with file built for iOS Simulator-arm64
    ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/myuser/Projects/test/auth_sample/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/Pods_Runner.framework/Pods_Runner, building for iOS Simulator-x86_64 but attempting to link with file built for iOS Simulator-arm64
    ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/myuser/Projects/test/auth_sample/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/nanopb/nanopb.framework/nanopb, building for iOS Simulator-x86_64 but attempting to link with file built for iOS Simulator-arm64
    Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
      "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GTMOAuth2KeychainCompatibility", referenced from:
          objc-class-ref in GoogleSignIn(GIDAuthStateMigration_bdf842e92d17b12b5f020e0e721bd017.o)
      "_OBJC_CLASS_$_OIDURLQueryComponent", referenced from:
          objc-class-ref in GoogleSignIn(GIDSignIn_f05654be6d1b2af59ab6df426a0c4eb9.o)
      "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GTMSessionFetcher", referenced from:
          objc-class-ref in GoogleSignIn(GIDSignIn_f05654be6d1b2af59ab6df426a0c4eb9.o)
      "_OBJC_CLASS_$_OIDServiceConfiguration", referenced from:
          objc-class-ref in GoogleSignIn(GIDSignIn_f05654be6d1b2af59ab6df426a0c4eb9.o)
      "_OIDResponseTypeCode", referenced from:
          -[GIDSignIn authenticateInteractivelyWithOptions:] in GoogleSignIn(GIDSignIn_f05654be6d1b2af59ab6df426a0c4eb9.o)
      "_OBJC_CLASS_$_OIDAuthorizationService", referenced from:
          objc-class-ref in GoogleSignIn(GIDAuthentication_7b83cc27af8929ec7e4c9760d73a0f31.o)
          objc-class-ref in GoogleSignIn(GIDSignIn_f05654be6d1b2af59ab6df426a0c4eb9.o)
      "_OIDOAuthErrorResponseErrorKey", referenced from:
          +[GIDAuthentication handleTokenFetchEMMError:completion:] in GoogleSignIn(GIDAuthentication_7b83cc27af8929ec7e4c9760d73a0f31.o)
      "_OBJC_CLASS_$_OIDIDToken", referenced from:
          objc-class-ref in GoogleSignIn(GIDGoogleUser_2bdd4a676c033bc6ca21970e75d9159c.o)
          objc-class-ref in GoogleSignIn(GIDAuthentication_7b83cc27af8929ec7e4c9760d73a0f31.o)
          objc-class-ref in GoogleSignIn(GIDSignIn_f05654be6d1b2af59ab6df426a0c4eb9.o)
      "_OBJC_METACLASS_$_GTMAppAuthFetcherAuthorization", referenced from:
          _OBJC_METACLASS_$_GTMAppAuthFetcherAuthorizationWithEMMSupport in GoogleSignIn(GIDAuthentication_7b83cc27af8929ec7e4c9760d73a0f31.o)
         (maybe you meant: _OBJC_METACLASS_$_GTMAppAuthFetcherAuthorizationEMMChainedDelegate, _OBJC_METACLASS_$_GTMAppAuthFetcherAuthorizationWithEMMSupport )
      "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GTMAppAuthFetcherAuthorization", referenced from:
          _OBJC_CLASS_$_GTMAppAuthFetcherAuthorizationWithEMMSupport in GoogleSignIn(GIDAuthentication_7b83cc27af8929ec7e4c9760d73a0f31.o)
          objc-class-ref in GoogleSignIn(GIDAuthentication_7b83cc27af8929ec7e4c9760d73a0f31.o)
          objc-class-ref in GoogleSignIn(GIDSignIn_f05654be6d1b2af59ab6df426a0c4eb9.o)
          objc-class-ref in GoogleSignIn(GIDAuthStateMigration_bdf842e92d17b12b5f020e0e721bd017.o)
         (maybe you meant: _OBJC_CLASS_$_GTMAppAuthFetcherAuthorizationEMMChainedDelegate, _OBJC_CLASS_$_GTMAppAuthFetcherAuthorizationWithEMMSupport )
      "_OIDOAuthTokenErrorDomain", referenced from:
          ___46-[GIDAuthentication refreshTokensWithHandler:]_block_invoke in GoogleSignIn(GIDAuthentication_7b83cc27af8929ec7e4c9760d73a0f31.o)
      "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GTMKeychain", referenced from:
          objc-class-ref in GoogleSignIn(GIDAuthStateMigration_bdf842e92d17b12b5f020e0e721bd017.o)
      "_OBJC_CLASS_$_OIDAuthState", referenced from:
          objc-class-ref in GoogleSignIn(GIDAuthentication_7b83cc27af8929ec7e4c9760d73a0f31.o)
          objc-class-ref in GoogleSignIn(GIDSignIn_f05654be6d1b2af59ab6df426a0c4eb9.o)
      "_OBJC_CLASS_$_OIDAuthorizationRequest", referenced from:
          objc-class-ref in GoogleSignIn(GIDSignIn_f05654be6d1b2af59ab6df426a0c4eb9.o)
      "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FLTFirebaseCorePlugin", referenced from:
          objc-class-ref in GeneratedPluginRegistrant.o
      "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FLTFirebaseAuthPlugin", referenced from:
          objc-class-ref in GeneratedPluginRegistrant.o
    ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
    clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
    note: Using new build system
    note: Planning
    note: Build preparation complete
    note: Building targets in dependency order
    /Users/myuser/Projects/test/auth_sample/ios/Runner.xcodeproj: warning: The linked framework 'Pods_Runner.framework' is missing one or more architectures required by this target: x86_64. (in target 'Runner' from project 'Runner')

Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 12.
```

I have a mac mini 2020 with M1 architecture and I'm running the latest version of xcode 13.

It seems that some libraries can't be compiled for the arm architecture, and since the iPhone simulator uses that architecture the build fails.

I have also set up the `project.pbxproj` file for excluding the 9386 and arm64 architectures:

```
"EXCLUDED_ARCHS[sdk=iphonesimulator*]" = "i386 arm64";
```

Do you have any idea on how to solve this? This issue started when I integrated the `google_sign_in` dependency.

**UPDATE**:

Results for `flutter doctor -v` :

```
 ~/Projects/test/auth_sample: flutter doctor                                                                                                                                                                              
    [✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.8.0, on macOS 12.1 21C52 darwin-arm, locale en-IT)
    • Flutter version 2.8.0 at /Users/myuser/Src/flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision cf44000065 (7 days ago), 2021-12-08 14:06:50 -0800
    • Engine revision 40a99c5951
    • Dart version 2.15.0

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 31.0.0)
    • Android SDK at /Users/myuser/Library/Android/sdk
    • Platform android-31, build-tools 31.0.0
    • Java binary at: /Users/myuser/Library/Application Support/JetBrains/Toolbox/apps/AndroidStudio/ch-0/203.7784292/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.10+0-b96-7249189)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 13.2)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • CocoaPods version 1.11.2

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome

[✓] Android Studio (version 2020.3)
    • Android Studio at /Users/myuser/Library/Application Support/JetBrains/Toolbox/apps/AndroidStudio/ch-0/203.7784292/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.10+0-b96-7249189)

[✓] Android Studio (version 2020.3)
    • Android Studio at /Users/myuser/Library/Application Support/JetBrains/Toolbox/apps/AndroidStudio/ch-0/203.7678000/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.10+0-b96-7249189)

[☠] IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate Edition (the doctor check crashed)
    ✗ Due to an error, the doctor check did not complete. If the error message below is not helpful, please let us know about this issue at https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues.
    ✗ FormatException: Unexpected extension byte (at offset 5)
    • #0      _Utf8Decoder.convertSingle (dart:convert-patch/convert_patch.dart:1789:7)
      #1      Utf8Decoder.convert (dart:convert/utf.dart:318:42)
      #2      InputStream.readString (package:archive/src/util/input_stream.dart:207:30)
      #3      new ZipDirectory.read (package:archive/src/zip/zip_directory.dart:40:30)
      #4      ZipDecoder.decodeBuffer (package:archive/src/zip_decoder.dart:19:30)
      #5      ZipDecoder.decodeBytes (package:archive/src/zip_decoder.dart:14:12)
      #6      IntelliJPlugins._findPluginXml (package:flutter_tools/src/intellij/intellij.dart:130:44)
      #7      IntelliJPlugins._readPackageVersion (package:flutter_tools/src/intellij/intellij.dart:141:40)
      #8      IntelliJPlugins.validatePackage (package:flutter_tools/src/intellij/intellij.dart:63:35)
      #9      IntelliJValidator.validate (package:flutter_tools/src/intellij/intellij_validator.dart:103:15)
      #10     asyncGuard.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/async_guard.dart:111:32)
      #11     asyncGuard.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/async_guard.dart:109:18)
      #12     _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1428:13)
      #13     _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1328:19)
      #14     _runZoned (dart:async/zone.dart:1863:10)
      #15     runZonedGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:1851:12)
      #16     runZoned (dart:async/zone.dart:1782:12)
      #17     asyncGuard (package:flutter_tools/src/base/async_guard.dart:109:3)
      #18     Doctor.startValidatorTasks (package:flutter_tools/src/doctor.dart:197:9)
      #19     Doctor.diagnose (package:flutter_tools/src/doctor.dart:301:47)
      #20     DoctorCommand.runCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/commands/doctor.dart:53:47)
      #21     FlutterCommand.verifyThenRunCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command.dart:1290:12)
      <asynchronous suspension>
      #22     FlutterCommand.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command.dart:1140:27)
      <asynchronous suspension>
      #23     AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
      <asynchronous suspension>
      #24     CommandRunner.runCommand (package:args/command_runner.dart:209:13)
      <asynchronous suspension>
      #25     FlutterCommandRunner.runCommand.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command_runner.dart:288:9)
      <asynchronous suspension>
      #26     AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
      <asynchronous suspension>
      #27     FlutterCommandRunner.runCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command_runner.dart:236:5)
      <asynchronous suspension>
      #28     run.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/runner.dart:62:9)
      <asynchronous suspension>
      #29     AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
      <asynchronous suspension>
      #30     main (package:flutter_tools/executable.dart:94:3)
      <asynchronous suspension>


[✓] IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate Edition (version 2021.3)
    • IntelliJ at /Users/myuser/Library/Application Support/JetBrains/Toolbox/apps/IDEA-U/ch-0/213.5744.223/IntelliJ IDEA.app
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart

[✓] IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate Edition (version 2021.2.3)
    • IntelliJ at /Users/myuser/Library/Application Support/JetBrains/Toolbox/apps/IDEA-U/ch-0/212.5457.46/IntelliJ IDEA.app
    • Flutter plugin version 61.2.4
    • Dart plugin version 212.5486

[✓] VS Code (version 1.63.1)
    • VS Code at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
    • Flutter extension version 3.29.0

[✓] Connected device (2 available)
    • iPhone 12 (mobile) • 9B4C7C94-F3AA-4370-820E-5CEAF6E0AA18 • ios            • com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-15-2 (simulator)
    • Chrome (web)       • chrome                               • web-javascript • Google Chrome 96.0.4664.110
```

Comment: run flutter doctor and attach along with it.

Comment: here is the discussion:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63607158/xcode-12-building-for-ios-simulator-but-linking-in-an-object-file-built-for-io

Answer (score 1):

for me to resolve this:

- flutter clean
- flutter pub get
- cd ios
- arch -x86_64 pod update

Comment: but after fix that problem i still found new problem with google_sign_in