# Why does Xcode build for arm64 even when excluded?

Tags: ios, xcode, build, x86-64, arm64

I am trying to solve a problem related to [Xcode 12, building for iOS Simulator, but linking in an object file built for iOS, for architecture 'arm64'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63607158/xcode-12-building-for-ios-simulator-but-linking-in-an-object-file-built-for-io)

As an experiment, I wanted to see if I could configure one of my frameworks to only build x86_64 for all cases.

Here is my config:
[image: xcode config]
You can see I have overridden the architectures to be x86_64 and I am excluding arm64. I am also only building active architectures only. There is no way that arm64 should ever be considered during a build.

And yet...

Here is the output of a build the very next moment. It's tons of source files that indicate they are still being compiled for arm64.

[image]

Can anyone explain this discrepancy? I am running the latest Xcode, 13.2.1, on a new M1 Max laptop.

Comment: Did you find any solution to this issue?

Comment: We were using a library that was not compiled for arm64. Once we received a version of this library that had arm64 support, I believe we were able to resolve this issue.