# Building ionic cordova app for iOS on M1 Mac

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, cocoapods, apple-m1, cordova-ios

@ionic/angular: 6.0.1 &
cordova-ios: 6.2.0

Hey there,

I just got my new M1 Macbook Pro setup and I'm trying to run the command

```
ionic cordova build ios
```

It's failing with

```
building for iOS Simulator, but linking in object file built for iOS, file 'FILE_PATH' for architecture arm64

clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

...

** BUILD FAILED **
```

I googled this and everything I'm finding online says

> Basically you have to exclude arm64 for simulator architecture both from your project and the Pod project,

and provide tutorials on how to do this via XCode example

https://stackguides.com/questions/63607158/xcode-12-building-for-ios-simulator-but-linking-in-object-file-built-for-ios.

When I look in XCode, I don't see a section for "Excluded Architectures". Even if I did see this, my build flow removes & adds back the ios platform so I would have to do this every time...

Then I see people are saying add a post_install script to PodFiles. When using Cordova/Ionic how would I add a post_install script for the PodFile?

If I plug my phone into the computer during the build, it works but this is not an ideal solution as I want it to be able to build a bunch of white-labeled apps without having my phone required to be plugged into my computer during this process.

Anybody have any solutions for this / information?

Update:
I got the builds to complete successfully using a terminal opening with Rosetta.
Steps to reproduce:

1. Got to Applications->Utilities
2. Duplicate Terminal
3. Rename 2nd terminal to Rosetta-Terminal
4. right click rosetta-terminal & click Get Info
5. Check "Open using Rosetta"
6. Do my builds via Rosetta-Terminal

Everything seems to be working now... I'm sure this isn't the "ideal" solution, but it works for now

Duplicate terminal

Answer (score 4):

For me, nothing worked except Rosetta.

Steps that worked for me:

1. Installed Rosetta (As it was not installed already)(Execute in terminal):

*softwareupdate --install-rosetta*

2. Right click xcode, check open with rosetta and then Open XCode.
3. Cmd+Shift+K -> Run Build

It will open the app in simulator/device

Comment: Worked for me (loaded emulator and opened app) but the app froze on the splash screen due to background services in the app, so it's a bit complicated, I'll post to here if I find an alternate fix.