# Xcode 12.4 Building for iOS Simulator, but linking in dylib built for iOS,

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, dylib

I am building a flutter chat app,

here on running it on an ios device, I am getting the below error.

```
ld: building for iOS Simulator, but linking in dylib built for iOS, file '/Users/drole/Documents/chat/ios/Pods/AgoraRtcEngine_iOS/AgoraAIDenoiseExtension.framework/AgoraAIDenoiseExtension' for architecture arm64
```

What should I do to resolve the error,
[I've tried surfing on the internet](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/657913) but I don't get a proper solution.

Comment: See here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63607158/xcode-12-building-for-ios-simulator-but-linking-in-an-object-file-built-for-io/64139830#64139830

Comment: Try googling without your specific file path and SDK names and you should find some results ;)

Answer (score 0):

in Podfile add this

```
post_install do |installer|
  projects = installer.aggregate_targets
   .map{ |t| t.user_project }
   .uniq{ |p| p.path }
   .push(installer.pods_project)
   installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
   end

  projects.each do |project|
   project.build_configurations.each do |config|
    config.build_settings['EXCLUDED_ARCHS[sdk=iphonesimulator*]'] = 
   'arm64'
   end

   project.save()
 end
 end
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

in Podfile add this or check this link
https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-native-ios/issues/487#issuecomment-1163332686

```
post_install do |installer|
  projects = installer.aggregate_targets
   .map{ |t| t.user_project }
   .uniq{ |p| p.path }
   .push(installer.pods_project)
   installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
   end

  projects.each do |project|
   project.build_configurations.each do |config|
    config.build_settings['EXCLUDED_ARCHS[sdk=iphonesimulator*]'] = 
   'arm64'
   end

   project.save()
 end
 end
```

Answer (score 0):

Follow the steps:

### Solution 1

**Right click on Xcode in applications folder**

**Get Info**

**Check Open using Rosetta**

**Open Xcode**

**Open project**

**Clean build folder**

**Run project**

By opening Xcode using Rosseta, no other build settings or configurations are needed.

### Solution 2

**Go to “Product” in the menu bar**

**Destination**

**Destination Architectures**

**Show both**

**Pick a simulator from the device dropdown menu that has Rosseta next to it.**

**Run project**

Solution 3

Go to the Pods track the error pod lib
[image]
in Excluded Architectures → in debug and release tap + button → in both debug and release.

[image]