# No such Module 'Flutter' : Xcode 13

Tags: ios, flutter, dart, module, podfile

I am trying to run my app on iphone device and constantly running into this error. I followed some answer to this error on stenter code hereack like removing the pod file and recreating it. Pasting the podfile for better understanding.-------------------------------------------------------------------

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '12.0'

# CocoaPods analytics sends network stats synchronously affecting flutter build latency.
ENV['COCOAPODS_DISABLE_STATS'] = 'true'

project 'Runner', {
  'Debug' => :debug,
  'Profile' => :release,
  'Release' => :release,
}

def flutter_root
  generated_xcode_build_settings_path = File.expand_path(File.join('..', 'Flutter', 'Generated.xcconfig'), __FILE__)
  unless File.exist?(generated_xcode_build_settings_path)
    raise "#{generated_xcode_build_settings_path} must exist. If you're running pod install manually, make sure flutter pub get is executed first"
  end

  File.foreach(generated_xcode_build_settings_path) do |line|
    matches = line.match(/FLUTTER_ROOT\=(.*)/)
    return matches[1].strip if matches
  end
  raise "FLUTTER_ROOT not found in #{generated_xcode_build_settings_path}. Try deleting Generated.xcconfig, then run flutter pub get"
end

require File.expand_path(File.join('packages', 'flutter_tools', 'bin', 'podhelper'), flutter_root)

flutter_ios_podfile_setup

target 'Runner' do
  use_frameworks!
  use_modular_headers!

  flutter_install_all_ios_pods File.dirname(File.realpath(__FILE__))
end

post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings["EXCLUDED_ARCHS[sdk=iphonesimulator*]"] = "arm64"
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

config.build_settings["EXCLUDED_ARCHS[sdk=iphonesimulator*]"] = "arm64"

Try Removing this line and follow this link

[Xcode 12, building for iOS Simulator, but linking in an object file built for iOS, for architecture 'arm64'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63607158/xcode-12-building-for-ios-simulator-but-linking-in-an-object-file-built-for-io)

Posted By Thomas Ward

Comment: Followed the above steps and The error got solved but now got this error "'Flutter/Flutter.h' file not found : FLTURLLauncherPlugin.h:4:8"

Comment: run flutter clean
and then build

you can open XCODE and under Product>Clean Build or something...

dont forget to pub get...

if problem still persist

run flutter pub cache repair
good internet good speed of task...

and run project again after flutter clean again...

Keep me posted if you don't find any solution...

an upvote is much appreciated if it helped you...