# Cocoapods EXCLUDED_ARCHS flag not being set during build

Tags: swift, cocoapods, podfile, xcode-build-settings

I am trying to build my project but kept getting 'No Module Found' when deploying to the simulator but not to an actual device. After digging around, I found I should add the  `arm64` to the *Excluded Archtiectures* section of the building settings for all my targets.

I used this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63607158/xcode-building-for-ios-simulator-but-linking-in-an-object-file-built-for-ios-f) as a reference, however the `arm64` is not being set.

Anyone see what I have done wrong?

```
post_install do |installer|

    installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
        target.build_configurations.each do |config|
            config.build_settings["ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH"] = "YES"
            config.build_settings["EXCLUDED_ARCHS[sdk=iphonesimulator*]"] = "arm64"
        end
    end

end
```

Comment: are you using any mac with m1 chip?

Comment: I am using an M1 Mac

Comment: run this code on m1:  arch -x86_64 pod install

Comment: you could also try opening your Xcode in rosetta mode

Answer (score 4):

You're likely using a binary pod that does not support the M1 Mac simulator. The option you're setting is excluding the M1 for the whole build to enable the project to build for devices and Intel simulators.

Contact the pod provider to ask them to add M1 support.

Comment: how do i find out which of my installed pods is the issue?