# Why is pod lib lint ignoring pod_target_xcconfig?

Tags: swift, cocoapods

I'm responsible for a cocoapod, which depends on another pod, which in turn depends on another pod.  I'm not responsible for either of the other pods.  When I run `pod lib lint` on my pod on an M1 mac it fails with the error:

> Building for iOS Simulator, but linking in dylib built for iOS, file '...' for architecture arm64

I've read the answers to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63607158/64239) SO post, and added

```
s.pod_target_xcconfig = { 'EXCLUDED_ARCHS[sdk=iphonesimulator*]' => 'arm64' }
s.user_target_xcconfig = { 'EXCLUDED_ARCHS[sdk=iphonesimulator*]' => 'arm64' }
```

to my podspec.  I've also tried adding `'ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH' => 'YES'`.  But I still get the same error.

Why is `pod lib lint` ignoring the excluded architectures, and is there a way I can lint my pod without building for arm64?

As I'm not responsible for the other pods I can't add arm64 support to them.

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

s.pod_target_xcconfig = { 'VALID_ARCHS' => 'x86_64 armv7 arm64' }

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).