# Could not find module 'Kingfisher' for target 'x86_64-apple-ios-simulator'

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, kingfisher

i add arm64 to my **Excluded Architectures** because i have pod and that works with this,[image: this picture]... after i added Kingfisher swift package manager, when i import that i receive this error

> Could not find module 'Kingfisher' for target 'x86_64-apple-ios-simulator'; found: arm64-apple-ios-simulator, at: /Users/amin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MKAMovies-dlhggzhzyxovkxfddvoeqlirqfxi/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Kingfisher.swiftmodule

how can i fix that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Xcode building for iOS Simulator, but linking in an object file built for iOS, for architecture 'arm64'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63607158/xcode-building-for-ios-simulator-but-linking-in-an-object-file-built-for-ios-f)

Comment: Referenced question explains why this may happen. For example maybe you forgot to exclude on Pods project

Comment: @jjquirckart no i tried that answers but my error still is showing, my problem is my pod works with arm64, and my package manager(kingfisher) works with x86_64

Answer (score -1, accepted):

if you installed your pod using:

> arch -x86_64 pod install

you should change it to:

> pod install

after doing that you don not need to change your **Excluded Architecture** to **arm64**