# I can't build my app with apple silicon m1 pro without using rosetta

Tags: ios, swift, apple-silicon

I have tried all the solutions I could find on the internet but none has worked, the application was created with an intel processor and I think it is some kind of problem with the creation of the project because the libraries that give me error adding them in a project from 0 work perfectly, I do not know if it is possible to update the project somehow and to stop using rosseta that slows xcode in such a way that it becomes insufferable to develop.

[Here is an image of the error xcode gives me when I try to run the application without rosetta](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zahAn.png)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Could not find module 'Kingfisher' for target 'x86\_64-apple-ios-simulator'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72841885/could-not-find-module-kingfisher-for-target-x86-64-apple-ios-simulator)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, when you want to run your previously created app on a simulator, you should run your simulators on rosetta as well. Therefore go to: Your HD -> Applications -> Xcode, right click and show package content -> Content -> Developer -> Applications -> Simulator.app

Here is the path:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Applications/Simulator.app
```

Open context menu -> change the settings of the Simulator.app in the information like you did for Xcode: Set checkmark for `Open with Rosetta`.

Later you could see if it is necessary to exclude some architectures like `arm64` in your build settings, see this image:

[image: Exclude Arm64 In Build Settings]