# While using Flutter, how do I resolve "Building for 'iOS-simulator', but linking in dylib built for 'iOS'"?

Tags: ios, flutter, mapbox, mapbox-gl

I have a flutter project that works as expected when running on a real iPhone / Android / Android simulator. I am getting this error in my flutter project when running the iOS simulator:

"Building for 'iOS-simulator', but linking in dylib (/ios/Pods/Mapbox-iOS-SDK/dynamic/Mapbox.framework/Mapbox) built for 'iOS'"

There have been multiple posts I have came across that seem to solve this problem, but none of them are using a Flutter application so i'm not sure how to solve it. [Solution 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63607158/xcode-building-for-ios-simulator-but-linking-in-an-object-file-built-for-ios-f), [Solution 2](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/658424).

It seems the problem comes down to either the [Mapbox_gl](https://pub.dev/packages/mapbox_gl) SDK I have installed is not compatible with arm64 simulator (I feel like this is unlikely considering how popular Mapbox is). Or something in my flutter settings does not allow the iOS simulator to run.

If the settings of my flutter project is what is screwing up my project I am unsure how to navigate and fix that problem. Can anyone provide me some help?